# Snapshot Options When Unable to Set Up LVM

Tags: containers, snapshot, docker, lxc

I am looking for ways to make it easy to encapsulate my "deployments" in a way such that I can take snapshots which allow

- transfer between hosts
- ability to restore to a previous point in time (snapshots)

I mainly use VPS providers (Xen/KVM), where I don't have control over setting up LVM on the filesystem. At the moment I am using Docker (wraps around LXC) in order to deploy my applications quickly and easily, but I usually mount the "state" information on the VM filesystem rather than within the container. This way if the server crashes/reboots, I don't lose anything. I then have to manually grab/package up this information whenever I want to move, and there is no option for point-in-time restore, such as with LVM.

It is tempting to move the state into the container so that I can "commit" the container at points in time, and then I can move host by simply saving/transferring/loading the container. This also allows restoring to a certain point in time by using `docker run` on the images that are generated from the commits, however this is somewhat dangerous and feels like "bad practice". I have been told not to let my containers "have a life of their own". Does anyone know of alternatives, such as virtual filesystems, or a "safe" way to leave the state inside the docker container.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are looking for **[data only container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496940/how-to-deal-with-persistent-storage-e-g-databases-in-docker)** "best practice".

You have to decouple your data and your app to 2 containers. In practice, you have to save your state f.e. to /data only in your app's filesystem. This way you can commit  the data container (mounted at /data) whenever you want, totally independently of the app container/image.

```
# create data volume "app-data"
sudo docker run -name app-data -v /data busybox true
# container exits immediately, it does not matter

sudo docker run --volumes-from app-data your-image
```

**EDIT:**

<del>You can commit app-data container to new image anytime, but this image is based on busybox every time you make a commit.</del>

Unfortunately, you cannot commit the app-data volume by docker commit and you cannot export (by docker export) the app-data volume by docker export (see [this](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/wiki/Volumes-&-persistent-data-storage)).

**EDIT2:**

You can make export of the app-data container by piping tar of the volume directory from the new container to stdout (base ubuntu image is ok):

```
sudo docker run --volumes-from app-data ubuntu tar -cO /data/ | gzip -c > snapshot.tgz
```

If you want to make incremental backups (to save some space), you can use tar to incremental backup only changes:

```
sudo docker run --volumes-from app-data ubuntu tar -cO /data/ -g /data/.tar.snar --exclude .tar.snar| gzip -c > snapshot-`date -u "+%F-%T"`.tgz
```

This will make an incremetal snapshot of the /data directory. It does not record deleted files, only changed or new files are recorded. You can make full backup anytime by deleting /data/.tar.snap file prior to running backup.

I am not sure how you data/state is structured but in case of text configuration files, I would use git for snapshots and versioning of /data directory (inside container: `git init /data`, `git add . && git commit -a -m "snapshot"`) and docker export for backup and transfer.

See this related links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496940/how-to-deal-with-persistent-storage-e-g-databases-in-docker
- http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/working_with_volumes/

Comment: Thank you! That is a great concept which means that one can follow the same procedure for moving deployments around without having to know/how where data is stored on a per-application basis. This also means I only need to transfer the data container between hosts as I can just pull the app-container from the registry on the new host. I was wrong in my question when I stated "This way if the server crashes/reboots, I don't lose anything." as the data isn't lost, one just needs to run `docker ps -a` to list the stopped containers and restart it.

Comment: Surely there is a large difference between using docker commit and docker export to to a tgz file which is that the former acts like incremental backups and the latter acts like a full backup. This results in the former using a lot less space when you take frequent snapshots/backups.

Comment: I just found that "Changes to a data volume are made directly, without the overhead of a copy-on-write mechanism." "Changes to a data volume will not be included at the next commit" This means that one cannot take point-in-time snapshots on the data container correct?

Comment: You can make "point-in-time" snapshots of the data container by commit  state to the image but snapshots as I have described them are not incremental backups! They do not share differences, every new commit will take the same space as the total size of the data directory. So there is not much difference by using export or commit. You can restart later your app with last snapshot by creating new app-data volume based on backup-data:revX instead of busybox.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the statement "Changes to a data volume will not be included at the next commit". Means that running a docker commit on a data container is pointless, the data will not be saved. As for the `sudo docker export app-data | gzip -c > backup.tgz` command, does that "lock" the volume to prevent writes going through whilst the process is taking place?

Comment: Ha, you are correct! Sorry, this does not work, even export does not export data volume! I have just try it. :( I will think about it I will update the answer appropriately.

Comment: @Programster Thank you for pointing this out! I need to update my own backup scheme for data volumes, currently I am using this (and it does not work).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46628/discussion-between-jiri-and-programster)