# How to list Docker mounted volumes from within the container

Tags: docker, mount, inspect

I want to list all container directories that are mounted volumes.

I.e. to be able to get similar info I get from

```
docker inspect --format "{{ .Volumes }}" <self>
```

But from within the container and without having `docker` installed in there.

I tried `cat /proc/mounts`, but I couldn't find a proper filter for it.

Comment: try to add to your `docker run command` the bind mount of  `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: I mean without installing docker inside and without running docker inside because that's an equivalent of giving sudo privileges to the inner container to the outside host.

Comment: There really isn't any way from within a container to identify Docker volume mounts (without exposing access to the Docker api).

Comment: you can "cheat" and add to your `docker run` command` a list of environment variables,  `--env-file=[]              Read in a file of environment variables`  (from the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run), but you provide it to your container, your container does not discover it

Comment: Why? The entire point of Docker is that storage volumes, network ports and container linkages are abstracted from the containerized application. This is what makes Docker containers portable.

Comment: There is no such thing as the perfect abstraction and sometimes you just need to do custom things. In this case I want to fix perms for all shared volumes because this issue is still open: [Make uid & gid configurable](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7198) and the idea is taking from [Hamy community wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28596874/511069) my code: https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/blob/dfecfc0d485d25199101e480e4ad18a0e58a1cbf/bin/start.sh#L366

Comment: If the mounted fs is ext4 try ```grep ext4 /etc/mtab | grep -v "\ \/etc"```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(EDIT - this may no longer work on Mac) <s>If your Docker host is OS X, the mounted volumes will be type osxfs (or fuse.osxfs). You can run a</s>

`mount | grep osxfs | awk '{print $3}'`

and get a list of all the mounted volumes.

If your Docker host is Linux (at least Ubuntu 14+, maybe others), the volumes appear to all be on `/dev`, but not on a device that is in your container's `/dev` filesystem. The volumes will be alongside `/etc/resolv.conf`, `/etc/hostname`, and `/etc/hosts`. If you do a `mount | grep ^/dev` to start, then filter out any of the files in `ls /dev/*`, then filter out the three files listed above, you should be left with host volumes.

`mount | grep ^/dev/ | grep -v /etc | awk '{print $3}'`

My guess is the specifics may vary from Linux to Linux. Not ideal, but at least possible to figure out.

Comment: Works with my Ubuntu host and guest. Which is what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This might have been correct at the time the answer was posted, but it seems things have changed since then: Running Docker on macOS 10.14 Mojave and none of the mounts inside one sample container are of type `osxfs`: `mount | sed -E -e 's|.*type ([^ ]+).*|\1|g' | sort | uniq | xargs` prints `cgroup devpts ext4 mqueue overlay proc sysfs tmpfs`.

Comment: @ssc I don't have any way to verify, so I'll take you word for it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to check what volumes are mounted *from inside a linux based container*  you can look up entries beginning with "/dev" in /etc/mtab, removing the /etc entries

```
$ grep "^/dev" /etc/mtab | grep -v " \/etc/"

/dev/nvme0n1p1 /var/www/site1 ext4 rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p1 /var/www/site2 ext4 rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can read from many of the comments you had, a container is initially nothing but a restricted, reserved part of resources that is totally cut away from the rest of your machine. It is not aware of being a Docker, and inside the container everything behaves as if it were a separate machine. Sort of like the matrix, I guess ;)

You get access to the host machine's kernel and its resources, but yet again restricted as just a filtered out set. This is done with the awesome "cgroups" functionality that comes with Unix/Linux kernels.

Now the good news: There are multiple ways for you to provide the information to your Docker, but that is something that you are going to have to provide and build yourself.

The easiest ad most powerful way is to mount the Unix socket located on your host at `/var/run/docker.sock` to the inside of your container at the same location. That way, when you use the Docker client inside your container you are directly talking to the docker engine on your host.

However, with great power comes great responsibility. This is a nice setup, but it is not very secure. Once someone manages to get into your docker it has root access to your host system this way.

A better way would be to provide a list of mounts through the environment settings, or clinging on to some made-up conventions to be able to predict the mounts.

(Do you realize that there is a parameter for mounting, to give mounts an alias for inside your Docker?)

Answer (score -1):

The docker `exec` command is probably what you are looking for.

This will let you run arbitrary commands inside an existing container.

For example:

```
docker exec -it <mycontainer> bash
```

Of course, whatever command you are running must exist in the container filesystem.

```
#docker  cp  >>>> Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem
docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH
docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH CONTAINER:DEST_PATH
```

to copy full folder:

```
docker cp ./src/build b081dbbb679b:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Note – This will copy build directory in container’s …/nginx/html/ directory to copy only files present in folder:

```
docker cp ./src/build/ b081dbbb679b:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Note – This will copy contents of build directory in container’s `…./nginx/html/ directory`

Docker Storage options:

> Volumes are stored in a part of the host filesystem which is managed by Docker(/var/lib/docker/volumes/ on Linux). Non-Docker processes should not modify this part of the filesystem. Volumes are the best way to persist data in Docker.
>
> When you create a volume, it is stored within a directory on the Docker host. When you mount the volume into a container, this directory is what is mounted into the container. This is similar to the way that bind mounts work, except that volumes are managed by Docker and are isolated from the core functionality of the host machine.
>
> A given volume can be mounted into multiple containers simultaneously. When no running container is using a volume, the volume is still available to Docker and is not removed automatically. You can remove unused volumes using docker volume prune.
>
> When you mount a volume, it may be named or anonymous. Anonymous volumes are not given an explicit name when they are first mounted into a container, so Docker gives them a random name that is guaranteed to be unique within a given Docker host. Besides the name, named and anonymous volumes behave in the same ways.
>
> Volumes also support the use of volume drivers, which allow you to store your data on remote hosts or cloud providers, among other possibilities.
>
> Bind mounts may be stored anywhere on the host system. They may even be important system files or directories. Non-Docker processes on the Docker host or a Docker container can modify them at any time.
>   Available since the early days of Docker. Bind mounts have limited functionality compared to volumes. When you use a bind mount, a file or directory on the host machine is mounted into a container. The file or directory is referenced by its full path on the host machine. The file or directory does not need to exist on the Docker host already. It is created on demand if it does not yet exist. Bind mounts are very performant, but they rely on the host machine’s filesystem having a specific directory structure available. If you are developing new Docker applications, consider using named volumes instead. You can’t use Docker CLI commands to directly manage bind mounts.
>
> One side effect of using bind mounts, for better or for worse, is that you can change the host filesystem via processes running in a container, including creating, modifying, or deleting important system files or directories. This is a powerful ability which can have security implications, including impacting non-Docker processes on the host system.
>
> tmpfs mounts are stored in the host system’s memory only, and are never written to the host system’s filesystem.
>
> A tmpfs mount is not persisted on disk, either on the Docker host or within a container. It can be used by a container during the lifetime of the container, to store non-persistent state or sensitive information. For instance, internally, swarm services use tmpfs mounts to mount secrets into a service’s containers.
>
> If you need to specify volume driver options, you must use --mount.
>     -v or --volume: Consists of three fields, separated by colon characters (:). The fields must be in the correct order, and the meaning of each field is not immediately obvious.
>   o In the case of named volumes, the first field is the name of the volume, and is unique on a given host machine. For anonymous volumes, the first field is omitted.
>   o The second field is the path where the file or directory will be mounted in the container.
>   o The third field is optional, and is a comma-separated list of options, such as ro. These options are discussed below.
>   • --mount: Consists of multiple key-value pairs, separated by commas and each consisting of a = tuple. The --mount syntax is more verbose than -v or --volume, but the order of the keys is not significant, and the value of the flag is easier to understand.
>   o The type of the mount, which can be bind, volume, or tmpfs. This topic discusses volumes, so the type will always be volume.
>   o The source of the mount. For named volumes, this is the name of the volume. For anonymous volumes, this field is omitted. May be specified as source or src.
>   o The destination takes as its value the path where the file or directory will be mounted in the container. May be specified as destination, dst, or target.
>   o The readonly option, if present, causes the bind mount to be mounted into the container as read-only.
>   o The volume-opt option, which can be specified more than once, takes a key-value pair consisting of the option name and its value.

Answer (score -1):

The following command seems to work both on Unix and MacOs

`grep overlay /etc/mtab | sed 's#.*/#/#;s# .*##'`