# Mount volume through boot2docker to the postgres container

Tags: macos, postgresql, docker, boot2docker

I'm trying to run the container of `postgres` image with `boot2docker` on OSX.

This command works well on my Ubuntu:

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
```

but OSX says:

```
fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... initdb: could not create directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/global": Permission denied
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

`chmod` doesn't help.

I've tried option `--user $(id -u):$(id -g)`. It breaks container on Ubuntu, and it changes the error on OSX.

Ubuntu: `chmod: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data’: Operation not permitted`

OSX: `chmod: changing permissions of ‘/run/postgresql’: Operation not permitted`

As it works for Ubuntu I want to run it on OSX, without creating my own images.
But I have no idea how to deal with this error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a [known boot2docker issue](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/581) 
There's [several](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/581#issuecomment-60094448) workarounds but no solution there

```
#1) Overriding the /Users default share on boot2docker start:
boot2docker --vbox-share=$(pwd)/share-location=share-name up
#2) boot2docker ssh in and mount the custom share:
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=999,gid=50 share-name [SHARE-FULL-PATH]/share-location
```

Answer (score 1):

Mounting local folders into docker containers is not a good practice. It quite often results into [problems with file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544282/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-permissions-for-docker-shared-volumes).

The better solution would be to change your setup using a [volume container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container) instead. There are also good concepts for [volume container backups](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).

Comment: I tried to do it with volume containers. The same problem.