# What permissions do I need to enable for Docker volumes to work?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, docker

Let's say I have a Docker container that holds some data. I want this data to persist - if the container is stopped, removed, upgraded etc. I still want the data to be in an accessible location on the host OS filesystem.

Currently, my solution is to create a directory `/srv/service-name` on my host (I use Ubuntu 14.10) and then run my service with the `-v /srv/service-name:/path/inside/container` argument.

By trial and error I found out that sometimes the container is unable to write to this, because it doesn't have the right permissions. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23544282/1042555) where data-only containers are given as a solution. Well, I don't want to use containers because it seems needlessly complicated for what I am doing. I'd rather just keep mounting the directories with `-v`.

So, how can I set the right permissions on the directory I am mounting?

Answer (score 5):

> So, how can I set the right permissions on the directory I am mounting?

There's nothing special about Docker volumes: in order for a process to write to a directory, the ownership and permissions on that directory need to allow writing.

By default, processes in a Docker container are running as `root` and are able to write pretty much anywhere, absent additional restrictions imposed by something like selinux.

If you have a process in a container that is *not* running as root, it is up to you to ensure that any volumes you expose to the container have appropriate ownership.  You have basically two choices:

1. Set the permissions on the source directory from the host.

   If your process is running as user `httpd` inside a container, you will need to determine the numeric UID associated with that user and then `chown` the directory to the appropriate user ID.  E.g., if user `httpd` inside the container is UID 48, then on the host:

   ```
   chown 48 /srv/webserver
   ```

   As you probably expect, this means that running `ls -l` on the host may return a different username, because there is no guarantee that UIDs in the container match UIDs on the host.
2. Set permissions in an `ENTRYPOINT` script

   If you are building your own images, you can run containers as `root`, and then have an `ENTRYPOINT` script that is responsible for (a) setting ownership and permissions and then (b) switching to a non-privileged user to run your `CMD`.