# Docker can't write to directory mounted using -v unless it has 777 permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, docker

I am using the [docker-solr](https://github.com/makuk66/docker-solr) image with docker, and I need to mount a directory inside it which I achieve using the `-v` flag.

The problem is that the container needs to write to the directory that I have mounted into it, but doesn't appear to have the permissions to do so unless I do `chmod 777` on the entire directory. I don't think setting the permission to allows all users to read and write to it is the solution, but just a temporary workaround.

Can anyone guide me in finding a more canonical solution?

Edit: I've been running docker without `sudo` because I added myself to the docker group. I just found that the problem is solved if I run docker with `sudo`, but I am curious if there are any other solutions.

Comment: What user is the application inside the image running as? If it is running as `solr` user then chances are it won't be able to write to host directory unless permissions are set to allow `solr` user (with uid as seen inside the container) to write to it. This amazing [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955361/what-permissions-do-i-need-to-enable-for-docker-volumes-to-work/31955607#31955607) by @larsks might help you in setting appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More recently, after looking through some official docker repositories  I've realized the more idiomatic way to solve these permission problems is using something called [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) in tandem with an entry point script. For example if we take an existing docker project, for example solr, the same one I was having trouble with earlier.

The [dockerfile](https://github.com/makuk66/docker-solr/blob/master/5.3/Dockerfile) on Github very effectively builds the entire project, but does nothing to account for the permission problems.

So to overcome this, first I added the gosu setup to the dockerfile (if you implement this notice the version `1.4` is hardcoded. You can check for the latest releases [here](https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases)).

```
# grab gosu for easy step-down from root
RUN mkdir -p /home/solr \
    && gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4 \
    && curl -o /usr/local/bin/gosu -SL "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.4/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
    && curl -o /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc -SL "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.4/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture).asc" \
    && gpg --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && rm /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu
```

Now we can use gosu, which is basically the exact same as `su` or `sudo`, but works much more nicely with docker. From the description for gosu:

> This is a simple tool grown out of the simple fact that su and sudo have very strange and often annoying TTY and signal-forwarding behavior.

Now the other changes I made to the dockerfile were these adding these lines:

```
COPY solr_entrypoint.sh /sbin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /sbin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

just to add my entrypoint file to the docker container.

and removing the line:

```
USER $SOLR_USER
```

So that by default you are the root user. (which is why we have gosu to step-down from root).

Now as for my own entrypoint file, I don't think it's written perfectly, but it did the job.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

export PS1="\w:\u docker-solr-> "

# step down from root when just running the default start command
case "$1" in
    start)
        chown -R solr /opt/solr/server/solr
        exec gosu solr /opt/solr/bin/solr -f
    ;;
    *)
        exec $@
    ;;
esac
```

A docker run command takes the form:

```
docker run <flags> <image-name> <passed in arguments>
```

Basically the entrypoint says if I want to run solr as per usual we pass the argument `start` to the end of the command like this:

```
docker run <flags> <image-name> start
```

and otherwise run the commands you pass as root.

The `start` option *first* gives the solr user ownership of the directories and then runs the default command. This solves the ownership problem because unlike the dockerfile setup, which is a one time thing, the entry point runs every single time.

So now if I mount directories using the -d flag, before the entrypoint actually runs solr, it will chown the files *inside* of the docker container for you.

As for what this does to your files outside the container I've had mixed results because docker acts a little weird on OSX. For me, it didn't change the files outside of the container, but on another OS where docker plays more nicely with the filesystem, it might change your files outside, but I guess that's what you'll have to deal with if you want to mount files inside the container instead of just copying them in.