# Docker userns-remap cannot write to mounted directory

Tags: docker, namespaces

I am trying out the [userns-remap](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) feature of Docker to create a file inside a container as `root` user and have the owner of this file as `test` user on the host.

I've added the following to the `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "userns-remap": "test:test"
}
```

The remapping seems to have taken place based on the daemon logs

```
User namespaces: ID ranges will be mapped to subuid/subgid ranges of: test:test
```

and the entries `test:100000:65536` and `test:100000:65536` have been added to `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid/` files, respectively.

But when I start a container and try to create a file in the working dir, it fails

```
test@box:~$ docker run -v /home/test/tmp:/somedir -w /somedir -it ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
root@11ff6c42ffe1:/somedir# touch file.txt
touch: cannot touch 'file.txt': Permission denied

root@11ff6c42ffe1:/somedir# ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody nogroup 0 Mar 23 21:39 already_existing_file.txt

root@11ff6c42ffe1:/somedir# id root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

root@11ff6c42ffe1:/somedir# touch /file.txt
```

Creating the file in some other directory that is not mounted from the host works as expected.

Also, if 777 permission is granted to the mounted directory, in this case **/home/test/tmp** on the host, file can be created successfully from inside the container. However, the newly created file has the following permissions on the host:

```
ls -l /home/test/tmp
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 165536 165536 0 march 29 01:36 file.txt
```

User with id 165536 is not present in the /etc/passwd which brings us back to the start. I would expect that the **root** user inside the container has the same permissions as the **test** user on the host and that the files created by **root** user in the container have the owner on the host that is mapped using userns-remap, i.e. **test**.

It is stated in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/#user-namespace-known-limitations) that

> ...if volumes are mounted from the host, file ownership must be
>   pre-arranged need read or write access to the volume contents.
>
> ... One notable restriction is the inability to use the mknod command.
>   Permission is denied for device creation within the container when run
>   by the root user.

Does this mean that **root** user inside the container cannot create files/directories inside the mounted directory, even though the owner of the mounted directory is the user that **root** maps to using userns-remap, in this case **test**?

Any ideas how to make the working directory also writable by the user inside the container?

---

**Docker version**: 18.03.0
**Ubuntu version**: 16.04.1
**Kernel version**: 4.13.0-36-generic

Steps to reproduce

```
sudo adduser test
sudo usermod -aG docker test
sudo echo '{ "userns-remap": "test"}' >> /etc/docker/daemon.json
service docker restart
su - test
mkdir tmp
docker run -v /home/test/tmp:/somedir ubuntu:16.04 touch /somedir/file.txt
```

Here are some similar questions, but not quite the same, as I would like to make this work *without* modifying the Dockerfile:

- [Docker and --userns-remap, how to manage volume permissions to share data between host and container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291520/docker-and-userns-remap-how-to-manage-volume-permissions-to-share-data-betwee) - exactly what is asked in this question, too, but there was no answer for 2 years, so keeping this question open
- [docker non-root bind-mount permissions, WITH --userns-remap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058552/docker-non-root-bind-mount-permissions-with-userns-remap)
- [Can I control the owner of a bind-mounted volume in a docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140911/can-i-control-the-owner-of-a-bind-mounted-volume-in-a-docker-image)
- [Docker can't write to directory mounted using -v unless it has 777 permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001523/docker-cant-write-to-directory-mounted-using-v-unless-it-has-777-permissions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to answer your question, the best way is to use 'user namespace' feature of the docker engine.

here's an example of how to use.
let's say your host user is `myuser` with id `3000`

add `myuser:3000:65536` to your */etc/subuid* and */etc/subgid* files

update your /etc/docker/daemon.json with this:

```
{
  "userns-remap": "myuser"
}
```

don't forget to restart your docker engine :)

and that's it , all files belonging to your `myuser` local account will belong to id `0` is your container and the opposite will true as well.

This should help you fix your issue.

Let me know

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: My /etc/subuid was sullivan:100000:65536 and removing the two extra 0 did the tricks. But what is the difference? Any side effects from our OS? Could you please explain a bit @Xinity?

Comment: @Soullivaneuh See https://systemd.io/UIDS-GIDS/ for a good explanation of these files, if you do it like you do, then basically the docker process can map to any regular user on your machine.

Comment: i.e. I wouldn't mess with these files if it's working already, but otherwise I'd add two rows "myuser:1000:1" and keep "myuser:10000:65536" for better isolation.

Comment: It obviously doesn't fix the issue as it will still get permission denied while writing to existing sub-directories. It seems like the whole `userns-remap` stuff is poorly implemented and doesn't solve the only problem it was supposed to solve: root-owned files in bind mounts.

Comment: container root uid (0) maps to host myuser uid (3000), but can I also map container regular uid (1000) to host myuser id (3000)? or, worst case scenario, can I safely map container 1000 to host 1000 without mapping container 0 to host 0?