# How do I write to a volume container as non-root in docker?

Tags: docker

How do I mount a volume writable by a non-root container user? I am ok with either the volume being owned by the non-root user or permissions being set to 777.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
RUN adduser -D myuser
USER myuser
```

Build image:

```
docker build -t example .
```

Run image, see /app unwritable by user

```
% docker run -i -t -v myapp:/app example /bin/sh
/ $ whoami
myuser
/ $ ls -lha / | grep app
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Nov 12 21:01 app
/ $
```

We can see app is globally readable but only writable by root.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544282/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-permissions-for-docker-shared-volumes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is not yet supported, and is studied in [issue 2259](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2259).
That affect other images like [docker-java](https://github.com/redhat-developer/docker-java/issues/4).

Basically, you have to [chown and copy (with the right user) your data in the volume](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2259#issuecomment-111659961), which is not very convenient.

Comment: In this case, the volume is a container, so no workaround. :( I'm going to drive it externally, perform volume based actions as root and others as a separate user with -u. Thanks for pointing me to this bug.