# Docker: Give container user write access to host directory

Tags: git, docker, drools, drools-guvnor, kie

I'm trying to run KIE Drools Workbench in docker.

If I stop the container, I lose my git repo, and this is getting super annoying (because the KIE UI forces you to upload your rules one by one).

Instead I want the container to use a host dir for its git repo.

So I've tried mapping a local host dir /opt/git to where I figured it stores the git repo

```
docker run -v /opt/git:/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/.niogit -d --name drools-brms jboss/brms:6.3.0.Final
```

But I get:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Creating directories for /opt/git/.niogit/system.git failed
```

/opt/git is owned by root on the host.  Is there any way to give chown permissions to the jboss user who only exists in the container?

Doesn't seem like it :/

Comment: Probably easier to `chown` your host folder to a host user with the same uid as the jboss user inside the container

Comment: Have you tried running with the `--privileged` flag?

Comment: --privileged didn't fix it.  I think it's an ownership issue.  Will try work out how to do the UID solution.  Any helpful links appreciated.

Comment: I'll try named containers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544282/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-permissions-for-docker-shared-volumes