# docker container / image not saving changes

Tags: docker, virtualization, docker-machine, docker-container

I pulled a MySQL docker(latest) & after running it I am trying to commit my container after adding some Data & New Schema's & tables in this mysql docker instance.

For Reference i am following this link -> http://www.servermom.org/pull-docker-images-run-docker-containers/3225/

But even after trying with multiple variations i am not achieving what i intend to. So what i am doing is after adding new tables and schema to my container i am committing & pushing to Docker hub as mentioned in the link.

After that i am deleting deleting the 1st pulled image as i have added new data to a container and committed as a new image with a different Tag .. i am deleting the 1st pulled image. (The reason i am doing this is because lets say if i am changing my machine i can get my data intact when i do a docker pull of my committed image)

Just like git if i commit & push and lets say my machine broke down so in the new machine i just have to do a git pull and i will get everything without any loss. So i am not able to understand how any why docker is not saving changes

Answer (score 0):

Data for mysql image is stored in a volume. That means that the files inside that volume are not part of the image, but stored on the host and assigned to one or more running containers.

To achieve what you want I see 2 options:

1) build a custom mysql image, where you change the storage path of mysql outside of a volume (or simply create a new mysql image without volumes).

2) you can extend the image and include the schema modification commands at container startup with a custom run script/entrypoint

Here is the documentation page about volumes: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/

Comment: Talking about option-1  I have simply pulled a mysql image using docker pull mysql:latest . and on that i have added my schema & data to that .. Is that you mean to say ..??.

Comment: Nope. If you look [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/0590e4efd2b31ec794383f084d419dea9bc752c4/5.7/Dockerfile) (this is the Dockerfile of the image you are using) there is an instruction at line 68 that says: `VOLUME /var/lib/mysql` . This directory is where the mysql images stores its data. So, when you run an insert in the running container, the only path in the container that changes is /var/lib/mysql. Since this is a Volume, that change is not saved in the image, even if you commit it. This is part of how docker works.

Comment: If you want to make the data changes persist inside an image, you need to customize the original image by editing in the mysql config file where mysql stores its data (actually /var/lib/mysql, you have to change it to somewhere else). In this way, the actual data of the DBMS will be persistend inside the image if you do a commit. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Also as u said that the Data is saved on disk and not on volume .. I also tried the example mentioned in the link which i provided In which we are pulling fresh Ubuntu image and updating it with packages and then Just installing mysql-server and checking the status of service that whether it is started or Not ... so here also i tried the same thing i committed & pushed the updated Ubuntu image with MySQL installed to the docker hub and then deleting the running containers ..

Comment: And then pulling the new updated ubuntu Image from the docker HUB (which i have committed) with tag and running that ... In that also MySQL service was not starting

Comment: This is a different story, in the question you are talking about the official mysql image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152545/discussion-between-aijaz-and-whites11).

Comment: Thanks for explaining but still the doubt is .. Lets say i remove the line Volume /var/lib/mysql from the Docker file .. Then where it will store the data ..and how it will commit the data to an image...??

And what if lets say i keep the Volume /var/lib/mysql intact to let Mysql store the data on that location...still it is container specific right ..?? what if i want to share the data ... or i want to commit and carry away this data on different systems ..???