# How to specify userid and groupid for volume mount point on Docker host

Tags: docker, permissions, containers, file-permissions, docker-volume

I have been frustrated by this issue for a while because this has been asked multiple times here, such as in [How to deal with persistent storage (e.g. databases) in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496940/how-to-deal-with-persistent-storage-e-g-databases-in-docker/20652410) and [What is the (best) way to manage permissions for Docker shared volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544282/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-permissions-for-docker-shared-volumes), but the answers do not address the issue at all.

The first "answer" says to just use `named volumes` instead of traditional `bind mounts`.  That solves nothing because when the named volume is mounted on the host, for instance at the default location `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<volume name>/_data`, then that mount point will have the `uid`/`gid` of the mount point inside the container.

The other "answer" given, before docker had named volumes, was to use a data-only container.  This exhibits the same exact problem.

The reason this is a huge problem for me is that I have many embedded machines on which I want to run the docker host, and the user may have a different `uid`/`gid` on each of these.  Therefore I cannot hardcode a `uid`/`gid` in a Dockerfile for the mount points for my persistent volumes, to achieve matching `id`s.

Here's an example of the problem:  Say my user is `foo` on the host, with `uid 1001` and `gid 1001`, and the user writing files to the volume inside the container has `uid 1002`. When I run the container, docker will `chown 1002:1002` the mount point dir on the host, and write files with this `uid`, which I can't even read/write with my user `foo`.

Visually (all these operations on the host):

```sh
$ docker volume create --driver local --opt type=volume --opt device=/home/<my_host_user>/logs --opt o=bind logs
logs
$ docker volume inspect logs
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-08-26T16:26:08+01:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/logs/_data",
        "Name": "logs",
        "Options": {
            "device": "/home/<myhostuser>/logs",
            "o": "bind",
            "type": "volume"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

```sh
$ pwd
/home/foo
$ mkdir logs && ls -ld logs
drwxr-xr-x 2 foo foo 4096 Aug 26 17:24 logs
```

Then running the container:

```sh
$ docker run --rm --name <cont_name> -it --net="host" --mount src=logs,target=/home/<container_user>/logs <my docker image>
```

And now the mount point:

```sh
$ ls -ld logs
drwxr-xr-x 2 1002 1002 4096 Aug 26 17:30 logs
$ ls -l logs/
total 4
-rw-r----- 1 1002 1002    0 Aug 26 17:30 log
-rw-r----- 1 1002 1002 2967 Aug 26 17:27 log.1
```

As you can see, the logs written to the volume have a `uid`/`gid` which doesn't correspond to something that exists on the host and which I can't access without root/sudo.

Now then, is there ANY way that docker can be told to map `uid`/`gid`s in the container to `uid`/`gid`s on the host, or even simpler to just use the specified `uid`/`gid` for the host mount point?

Comment: You can't specify `uid`/`gid` for a mount point; and it's a shame. If you want to mount you are forced with whatever `uid`/`gid` your `docker`-user has (usually `1000`:`1000`).

Answer (score 2):

my env:

1. Ubuntu 22.04
2. Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

---

create mount piont path with suitable permission.

```
# docker file 
RUN mkdir --parents '$volumeDir' ; chown --recursive '$userName':'$userGroup' '$volumeDir'
```

next, create container and mount volume .

```
# terminal
docker run --name=containerName --interactive  
--user=$userName:$userGroup --mount='source=volumeName,target==$volumeDir,readonly=false'  
imageName /bin/bash
```

you will got suitable permission