# Docker for windows cannot edit file in the guest due to access rights

Tags: docker, docker-compose

- My computer is running Windows 10 and [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/)
- I am using  [docker volume to code faster](https://dzone.com/articles/tutorial-how-to-use-docker-volumes-to-code-faster)
- the code is on the windows side. In the docker-compose.yaml I mount my workspace on the host tho the root of the apache server on the guest

```
volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html
```

- When I create the file *web\modules\custom\hello_world\hello_world.info.yml* on the host that file replicates on the guest side but remains empty:

```
PS C:\Users\jeanp\CONSULTANT\dockertest> docker exec -it my_drupal9_project_nginx /bin/bash
/var/www/html$ ls -al web/modules/custom/hello_world/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Aug  3 16:46 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Aug  3 16:46 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Aug  3 16:46 hello_world.info.yml
```

- (hello_world.info.yml has 0 bytes length and can be edited only by root)

  - On the guest side, when I try to edit hello_world.info.yml I cannot save it because it is marked as read-only

```
web/modules/custom/hello_world/hello_world.info.yml [Readonly] 0/0 100%
```

- On the guest side I asked who am I the answer is wodby:

```
/var/www/html$ whoami
wodby
```

- the other files on  in the image on the guest belongs to wodby

```
/var/www/html$ ls -al web
total 84
drwxr-xr-x    7 wodby    wodby         4096 Jul 22 02:17 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 wodby    wodby         4096 Jul 31 12:04 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 wodby    wodby         1025 Jul 22 02:17 .csslintrc
-rw-r--r--    1 wodby    wodby          151 Jul 22 02:17 .eslintignore
-rw-r--r--    1 wodby    wodby           41 Jul 22 02:17 .eslintrc.json
-rw-r--r--    1 wodby    wodby         2314 Jul 22 02:17 .ht.router.php
-rw-r--r--    1 wodby    wodby         7572 Jul 22 02:17 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--    1 wodby    wodby           94 Jul 22 02:17 INSTALL.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 wodby    wodby         3205 Jul 22 02:17 README.md
-rw-r--r--    1 wodby    wodby          315 Jul 22 02:17 autoload.php
drwxr-xr-x   12 wodby    wodby         4096 Jul 20 21:42 core
-rw-r--r--    1 wodby    wodby         1507 Jul 22 02:17 example.gitignore
-rw-r--r--    1 wodby    wodby          549 Jul 22 02:17 index.php
drwxr-xr-x    3 wodby    wodby         4096 Aug  3 16:46 modules
drwxr-xr-x    2 wodby    wodby         4096 Jul 22 02:17 profiles
-rw-r--r--    1 wodby    wodby         1586 Jul 22 02:17 robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x    3 wodby    wodby         4096 Jul 22 02:17 sites
drwxr-xr-x    2 wodby    wodby         4096 Jul 22 02:17 themes
-rw-r--r--    1 wodby    wodby          804 Jul 22 02:17 update.php
-rw-r--r--    1 wodby    wodby         4016 Jul 22 02:17 web.config
```

### My question is the following:

#### how to make that on the guest the files created through synchronisation from the host belongs to wodby and not root ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could benefit from setting up the folder and permissions via the Dockerfile prior to mounting the files in:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2259#issuecomment-48286811

Else this issue may be able to help you out, detailing a `volumes-from` pattern

[What is the (best) way to manage permissions for Docker shared volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544282/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-permissions-for-docker-shared-volumes)

Comment: In the DockerFile I added
VOLUME ["/var/www/html"]
USER www-data
I still have in the Docker-compose file:
volumes:
            - ./index.php:/var/www/html/index.php
in the container /var/www/html/index.php has still user/group: root/root and not www-data:www-data. That is my problem

Comment: I solved the problem by using Docker On Windows with Window Subsystem for Linux (WSL).
I add an Ubuntu on my windows. the Ubuntu has the same uid than the docker container