# Problems running a docker container (maybe permission issues)

Tags: docker, label-studio

I am new to docker and I was trying to deploy the software (https://github.com/HumanSignal/label-studio) to a debian VM. I followed the instructions here:
https://hub.docker.com/r/heartexlabs/label-studio#run-with-docker-compose
but it seems like I am getting a permission error after executing:

`` docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v `pwd`/mydata:/label-studio/data heartexlabs/label-studio:latest ``
The error log is on this screenshot:

[image]

My question is: Is it some docker issue (me not setting permissions to some path) or something else?
I tried executing with a root user and thus I expect the permissions to be no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same thing. Looks like a known issue:
https://github.com/HumanSignal/label-studio/issues/3595

They point to this:
https://labelstud.io/guide/install.html#PermissionError-Errno-13-Permission-denied-label-studio-data-media

Apparently the latest version requires root.

```
$ sudo docker run -it --user root -p 8080:8080 -v `pwd`/mydata:/label-studio/data heartexlabs/label-studio:latest chown -R 1001:root /label-studio/data/
$ sudo docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v `pwd`/mydata:/label-studio/data heartexlabs/label-studio:latest
```

Also, just opening up the perms on the folder works, but isn't secure.

```
$ sudo chmod 777 mydata
```

Comment: Thanks, executing the first two commands worked!

Answer (score 2):

You're facing a permissions issue due to the user inside the container not having the right access to the mounted volume. Instead of running as root, follow these steps:

Change ownership of your local mydata directory to match the user ID (e.g., 1001) inside the container:

```bash
sudo chown -R 1001:1001 mydata/
```

Run the container:

```bash
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v `pwd`/mydata:/label-studio/data heartexlabs/label-studio:latest
```

This way, the user inside the container has correct permissions without needing elevated privileges.
For further reference please read best practice suggestions in [What is the (best) way to manage permissions for Docker shared volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544282/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-permissions-for-docker-shared-volumes)