# How to update Docker image when there is new image version?

Tags: docker

I am currently running the official *ghost* Docker image, and use this image to build several containers.

If I want to update the my Docker image, I simply just use the command:

```
docker pull ghost
docker restart oldcontainer
```

Does it work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**. Updating an image will not affect the images that were built from that image, and **certainly not** affect the already-running containers that were created from this image.

One possible workflow would be sth. like this:

1. Pull new version of base image
2. Build new version of your own image on top of the image
3. Destroy and re-create your own containers from the newly-built image

Comment: so it means if I have the new image, then even restarting the containers based on the old image won't work.

Comment: Correct. Ideally, you would re-create the container from the (possibly updated) image. That's exactly the reason why it's discouraged to store application data inside a Docker container, btw. (see the answer linked in VonC's answer on that topic).

Answer (score 7):

A [`docker restart`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#restart) does a [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#stop) (or [`docker kill`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#kill) if the stop times out), which puts a container in an exit status, followed by a [`docker start`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#start), which starts the *same* container.

The fact that the image might have changed isn't detected at all in that process.

Removing and doing a full docker run with all the right parameter would pick up on an image change. See "[How to upgrade docker container after its image changed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26734402/6309)"