# How to restart a single container with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that contains 4 containers: `redis`, `postgres`, `api` and `worker`.

During the development of the `worker` container, I often need to restart it in order to apply changes. Is there any good way to restart a single container (e.g. `worker`) without restarting the others?

Comment: docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml restart worker

Comment: "Deploying Changes" section in https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/

Comment: Since you've explicitly asked for "applying changes", you may want to change the accepted answer to the BMitch's.

Answer (score 679, accepted):

It is very simple: Use the command:

```
docker-compose restart worker
```

You can set the time to wait for stop before killing the container (in seconds)

```
docker-compose restart -t 30 worker
```

Note that this will restart the container but without rebuilding it. If you want to apply your changes and then restart, take a look at the other answers.

Comment: for me it worked, but a general question if allowed here: does 'restart' take care of linked containers and update the /etc/hosts or doesn't a 'restart' change any IPs at all?

Comment: The containers are linked by name and typically the only IP you need to worry about is the external docker host IP (typically 192.168.99.100).  Where there can be some trouble is if you, say, restart a database container that other containers are connected to. The dependent containers will have to be resilient enough to reconnect.

Comment: The OP states that he needs to "restart it in order to apply changes". According to the docs the `docker-compose restart` commands will NOT apply any changes.

"If you make changes to your `docker-compose.yml` configuration these changes are not reflected after running this command."

Therefore use `docker-compose up -d --build`.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/restart/

Comment: nb, *worker* is the name given to the service in the yaml file and not anything that you see when running `docker ps -a`

Comment: This other answer is much better https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501539/292408, as `restart` doesn't apply changes even if you already ran a `docker-compose build <container name>`and this is a non-working/incorrect answer.

Comment: I edited it now to mention the fact that the rebuilding step is missing.

Comment: In case you need to restart using a prefix for your app `docker-compose -p myapp restart worker`

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here about what needs to be restarted. If it is just some change in the code that is stored in the container, then this command helps. If it is about changes in the Dockerfile that builds the image on which the container is running, then this command does not help. Most of the time in coding projects, you will not want to change the image, but the code that you run inside the container, and then this command is enough.

Answer (score 294):

The other answers to restarting a single node are on target, `docker-compose restart worker`. That will bounce that container, but not include any changes, even if you rebuilt it separately. You can manually `stop`, `rm`, `create`, and `start`, but there are much easier methods.

If you've updated your code, you can do the build and reload in a single step with:

```
docker-compose up --detach --build
```

That will first rebuild your images from any changed code, which is fast if there are no changes since the cache is reused. And then it only replaces the changed containers. If your downloaded images are stale, you can precede the above command with:

```
docker-compose pull
```

To download any changed images first (the containers won't be restarted until you run a command like the `up` above). Doing an initial stop is unnecessary.

And to only do this for a single service, follow the up or pull command with the services you want to specify, e.g.:

```
docker-compose up --detach --build worker
```

---

Here's a quick example of the first option, the Dockerfile is structured to keep the frequently changing parts of the code near the end. In fact the requirements are pulled in separately for the `pip install` since that file rarely changes. And since the nginx and redis containers were up-to-date, they weren't restarted. Total time for the entire process was under 6 seconds:

```
$ time docker-compose -f docker-compose.nginx-proxy.yml up --detach --build
Building counter
Step 1 : FROM python:2.7-alpine
 ---> fc479af56697
Step 2 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d04d0d6d98f1
Step 3 : ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9c4e311f3f0c
Step 4 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 85b878795479
Step 5 : ADD . /app
 ---> 63e3d4e6b539
Removing intermediate container 9af53c35d8fe
Step 6 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in a5b3d3f80cd4
 ---> 4ce3750610a9
Removing intermediate container a5b3d3f80cd4
Step 7 : CMD gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:80 --log-file - --access-logfile - --workers 4 --keep-alive 0
 ---> Running in 0d69957bda4c
 ---> d41ff1635cb7
Removing intermediate container 0d69957bda4c
Successfully built d41ff1635cb7
counter_nginx_1 is up-to-date
counter_redis_1 is up-to-date
Recreating counter_counter_1

real    0m5.959s
user    0m0.508s
sys     0m0.076s
```

Comment: This is interesting, but could it be used along with the `-no-cache` option? Say I added something into my `package.json` and need to re`RUN npm install` but the `Dockerfile` itself hasn't changed

Comment: @augustinriedinger If your input file is changed and you include that with a `COPY` command, that will break the cache automatically.

Comment: I did not get the `COPY` part of your comment. Indeed, editing the `Dockerfile` would work, but this is a dirty hack, especially since the file is tracked in `git`...

Comment: @augustinriedinger there are too many unknowns in your scenario to try to clarify this in a comment. This would be better handled as a separate question.

Comment: Well the question is [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529211/how-to-rebuild-and-update-a-container-without-downtime-with-docker-compose) and apparently you already linked there to this question :)

Comment: @augustinriedinger thanks. I'm mobile so I can't see the linked questions. From the steps in your question you should already have a `COPY` command in your Dockerfile. The `git pull` will update the package.json file and the build cache will break when docker sees you copy in a different file.

Comment: Thanks did not know about this behavior! I was using `ADD` instead of `COPY` but apparently the latter is a [best practice](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) so I'll go for it!

Comment: @augustinriedinger `ADD` will have the same result as `COPY` on the cache bust, but (as suggested in the best practices link) most don't need the extra capabilities so I don't even bother mentioning it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Restarting with changes applied is desired here.

Answer (score 78):

To restart a service with changes here are the steps that I performed:

```
docker-compose stop -t 1 worker
docker-compose build worker
docker-compose up --no-start worker
docker-compose start worker
```

Comment: If you need changes to apply with a build, you can easily do a `docker-compose up -d --build` and it will rebuild everything and restart any changed containers. No need for the stop first, with downtime, and separate create and start commands.

Comment: Yes, if you want to restart all services, but the OP only wants to restart a single service and not restart the others

Comment: See the answer I posted, in the example, the `up` will only recreated the container that had been changed and therefore needed a restart.

Comment: @BMitch somehow it doesn't always work for Rust containers. Even though I don't change anything in the source code, doing `docker-compose up -d --build` will often re-compile the project.

Answer (score 33):

Following command

```
docker-compose restart worker
```

will just STOP and START the container. i.e without loading any changes from the docker-compose.xml

STOP is similar to hibernating in PC . Hence stop/start will not look for any changes made in configuration file . To reload from the recipe of container (docker-compose.xml) we need to remove and create the container (Similar analogy to rebooting the PC )

So commands will be as following

```
docker-compose stop worker       // go to hibernate
docker-compose rm worker        // shutdown the PC 
docker-compose create worker     // create the container from image and put it in hibernate

docker-compose start worker //bring container to life from hibernation
```

Comment: +1, many thanks! For `rm` line option `-f` comes handy (no prompt) and with current docker `create` and `start` is merged as `up` (so in total we have 3 commands not 4), and for `up` option `-d` is useful (execution is in the background).

Answer (score 17):

Since some of the other answers include info on rebuilding, and my use case also required a rebuild, I had a better solution (compared to those).

There's still a way to easily target just the one single `worker` container that both rebuilds + restarts it in a single line, albeit it's not actually a single command.  The best solution for me was **simply rebuild and restart**:

```
docker-compose build worker && docker-compose restart worker
```

This accomplishes both major goals at once for me:

1. Targets the single `worker` container
2. Rebuilds and restarts it in a single line

Hope this helps anyone else getting here.

Answer (score 16):

## Restart Service with docker-compose file

```
docker-compose -f [COMPOSE_FILE_NAME].yml restart [SERVICE_NAME]
```

**Use Case #1:** If the COMPOSE_FILE_NAME is `docker-compose.yml` and service is worker

```
docker-compose restart worker
```

**Use Case #2:** If the file name is `sample.yml` and service is worker

```
docker-compose -f sample.yml restart worker
```

By default docker-compose looks for the `docker-compose.yml` if we run the `docker-compose` command, else we have flag to give specific file name with `-f [FILE_NAME].yml`

Comment: I get: ERROR: No containers to restart :(

Comment: Are you on the same network

Comment: i want to put this in Jenkins pipeline. If there is no Container created already using docker compose, will docker-compose restart work?

Answer (score 11):

The answer's here are talking about the reflection of the change on the docker-compose.yml file.

But what if I want to incorporate the changes I have done in my code, and I believe that will be only possible by rebuilding the image and that I do with following commands

**1. docker container stop**

```
docker stop container-id
```

**2. docker container removal**

```
docker rm container-id
```

**3. docker image removal**

```
docker rmi image-id
```

**4. compose the container again**

```
docker-compose up container-name
```

Comment: I think you should use the service key rather than container name `docker-compose up [service key]`

Comment: With container name it becomes easier as you can run it again by doing CTRL + R.

Comment: i want to put this in Jenkins pipeline. So whenever there is a new code push, docker will build a new image. If there is no Container created already for the first time then docker stop container-id will throw error. How will you solve it?

Comment: @RafiqueMohammed, in case of Jenkins pipeline, i think you would not want to take risk of bringing down your service, so the steps you should follow are
1. Bring up your new containers, with a different tag so that it does not override existing containers, you can use commit-id as tag
2. redirect your traffic to new container
3. Bring down your old container

Answer (score 10):

#### Restart container

If you want to just restart your container:

`docker-compose restart servicename`

Think of this command as "just restart the container by its name", which is equivalent to `docker restart` command.

#### Note caveats:

1. If you changed ENV variables they won't updated in container. You need to stop it and start again. Or, using single command `docker-compose up` will detect changes and recreate container.
2. As many others mentioned, if you changed `docker-compose.yml` file itself, simple restart won't apply those changes.
3. If you copy your code inside container at the build stage (in `Dockerfile` using `ADD` or `COPY` commands), every time the code changes you have to rebuild the container (`docker-compose build`).

#### Correlation to your code

`docker-compose restart` should work perfectly fine, if your code gets path mapped into the container by volume directive in `docker-compose.yml` like so:

```
services:

  servicename:
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

But I'd recommend to use live code reloading, which is probably provided by your framework of choice in DEBUG mode (alternatively, you can search for auto-reload packages in your language of choice). Adding this should eliminate the need to restart container every time after your code changes, instead reloading the process inside.

Answer (score 6):

Simple 'docker' command knows nothing about 'worker' container.
Use command like this

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml restart worker`

Comment: does not work -- new changes to the coker-compose.yml did not get applied on restart

Answer (score 5):

To apply changes to a Docker Compose file while only restarting a single service, you can use the `docker-compose` command with the `up` command and specify the service name. For example:

```bash
$ docker-compose up -d --no-deps myservice
```

This command will update the configuration for the `myservice` service and restart it, without touching any of the other services in the Compose file. The `-d` flag runs the services in the background, and the `--no-deps` flag tells Compose not to start any dependencies of the `myservice` service.

Alternatively, you can use the `restart` command to restart a single service:

```bash
$ docker-compose restart myservice
```

This will apply the latest configuration for the `myservice` service and restart it.

Note that this command will not apply any changes to the Compose file itself, it will only restart the service using the current configuration.

Answer (score 1):

After making changes, you need to pull the changes into the server and then reacreate the container. So as the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/) shows:

```
docker-compose pull worker && docker-compose up -d --no-deps worker
```

`pull worker` will make only this project to be pulled to the server, and `--no-deps` will prevent from restart containers the `worker` container depends on.

Answer (score 0):

Besides that, if you need also to build the container one more time before waking up again, you could follow this few steps:

### Disclaimer

- I assume that you keep working with a `compose.yaml` file and you have a few "others" containers running.
- The current `worker` container do not depends on any other.

### Recipe

```bash
# You can verify the current working containers before apply the changes.
docker compose -f compose.yaml ps -a

# Stop the container in order to remove the image.
docker compose -f compose.yaml stop worker

# Remove the `worker` container.
# A message will prompt. Press `y` (means "yes") in order to continue.
docker compose -f compose.yaml rm worker

# Query the image that you need to remove, then remove it.
docker images | grep worker
IMAGE_ID=X && docker rmi $IMAGE_ID

# Build and waking up the `worker` container/service.
docker compose -f compose.yaml up worker

# Once again, verify the current working containers after apply the changes.
docker compose -f compose.yaml ps -a
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this thread now that I had a similar issue after upgrading from the old "docker-compose" to the newer "docker compose" and fixed it the following way:

```
docker compose restart -f /path/to/docker-compose.yml restart
```

I thought this solution was not pretty, as it contains two times the restart command but I have not found a solution that works with my setup, as I have different docker-compose compartments in different folders that I wanted to use.