# How to rebuild and update a container without downtime with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I enjoy a lot using docker-compose.

Eg. on my server, when I want to update my app with minor changes, I only need to `git pull origin master && docker-compose restart`, works perfectly.

But sometimes, I need to rebuild (eg. I added an npm dependency, need to run `npm install` again).

In this case, I do `docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose restart`.

I would expect this to :

- create a new instance of my container
- stop the existing container (after the newer has finished building)
- start the new one
- optionally remove the old one, but this could be done manually

But in practice it seems to restart the former one again.

Is it the expected behavior?

How can I handle a rebuild and start the new one **after** it is built?

Maybe I missed a specific command? Or would it make sense to have it?

Comment: Others have already hit on the correct answer here. This answer to a similar question may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39501539/596285

Answer (score 60, accepted):

from the manual [docker-compose restart](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/restart/)

> If you make changes to your docker-compose.yml configuration these
>   changes will not be reflected after running this command.

you should be able to do

```
$docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build <service_name>
```

The `--no-deps` will not start linked services.

Comment: Each time I use your answer, the *`--no-deps` will not start linked services* scares me. Could you be more specific on what this means/implies?

Comment: that's a good question, you should ask it...   in short - Service links create environment variables which allow containers to communicate with each other within a stack, or with other services outside of a stack. You can specify service links explicitly when you create a new service or edit an existing one, or specify them in the stackfile for a service stack.   BUT you really should use network in your compose file.

Comment: Looks like service_name is optional and it will just rebuild all your services if left off.

Comment: `docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build # [servicename]`

Comment: This can't be correct, as docker must remove and then replace said container, resulting in downtime (however short, still downtime).

Comment: I've confirmed my hunch with a reproducable example, be careful with this answer if your container is exposed at a port and you expect truly constant uptime. With this answer there WILL be a short 1-5 second window in which any pings to that container's exposed port will fail.

Answer (score 57):

The problem is that `restart` will restart your current containers, which is not what you want.

As an example, I just did this

- change the docker file for one of the images
- call `docker-compose build` to build the images
- call `docker-compose down`<sup>1</sup> and `docker-compose up`

  - `docker-compose restart` will NOT work here
  - using `docker-compose start` instead also does not work

To be honest, i'm not completly sure you need to do a `down` first, but that should be easy to check.<sup>1</sup> The bottomline is that you need to call `up`. You will see the containers of unchanged images restarting, but for the changed image you'll see `recreating`.

The advantage of this over just calling `up --build` is that you can see the building-process first before you restart.

1: from the comments; down is not needed, you can just call `up --build`. Down has some "down"-sides, including possible being destructive to your (volume-)data.

Comment: `docker-compose down` is not required, `up` will detect the build has been updated and recreate the containers.  Also as the other answers have noted op will probably need `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Actually I should say `down` is a _bad_ idea. It destroys everything, which could include volume data in some setups.

Comment: you should not have data in a container anyway, if it is not a data container that is, but the point is valid.

Comment: Local [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#data-volumes), either defined in compose or autogenerated by a Dockerfile, will be destroyed by a down.

Comment: @Matt to keep the argument (which is a good one btw) clear I have added it a bit more clearly in the edit / disclaimer

Comment: I'll go for the `docker-compose up -d --build` but can I use it with a `--no-cache` option as well?

Answer (score 53):

Use the `--build` flag to the `up` command, along with the `-d` flag to run your containers in the background:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

This will rebuild all images defined in your compose file, then restart any containers whose images have changed.

`-d` assumes that you don't want to keep everything running in your shell foreground. This makes it act more like `restart`, but it's not required.

Comment: This one works for me the best from all the suggestions.

Comment: I also agree with this answer, worked perfect, ofc it's not a zero downtime solution since you'll need to use load balancers like traefik but this one did the trick with minimal downtime

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @jkinkead!

Answer (score 14):

Don't manage your application environment directly. Use deployment tool like [Rancher](https://rancher.com/) / Kubernetes. Using one you will be able to upgrade your dockerized application without any downtime and even downgrade it should you need to.

Running Rancher is as easy as running another docker container as this tool is available [in the Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/rancher/server/).

Comment: Can you please add instructions for doing the same using Rancher?

Answer (score 10):

You can use Swarm. Init swarm first by `docker swarm init` command and use `healthcheck` in docker-compose.yml.

Then run below command:

`docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml project_name`

instead of

`docker-compose up -d`.

When docker-compose.yml file is updated only run this command again:

`docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml project_name`

Docker Swarm will create new version of services and stop old version after that.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did started to use swarm, it is a decent solution though it is still harder to get started with than compose. Few things are missing (`docker stack logs`, using compose file by default to avoid writing it in commands etc.). IMHO it is a pity that compose doesn't include rolling updates by default, as this is the feature users lack the most.

Comment: Or for the last command, we could update the specific service by `docker service update --force drnext_back_server`.

Answer (score 6):

Though the accepted answer shall work to rebuild the container before starting the new one as a replacement, it is ok for simple use case, but the container will still be down during new container initialization process. If this is quite long, it can be an issue.

I managed to achieve rolling updates with `docker-compose` (along with a `nginx` reverse proxy), and detailed how I built that in this github issue: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1786#issuecomment-579794865

Hope it can help!

Answer (score 3):

Run the following commands:

```
docker-compose pull

docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build <service_name>
```

As the top rated answer mentioned

```
docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build <service_name>
```

will restart a single service without taking down the whole compose.

I just wanted to add to the top answer in case anyone is unsure how to update an image without restarting the container.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

`docker-compose restart` in your case could be replaced with `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate`, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Answer (score 0):

Running `docker-compose up` while docker-compose is in the running state, will recreate container that got their configuration changed.

Thats the easiest way, and it will only affect containers that got their configuration changed.

```
root@docker:~# docker-compose up
traefik is up-to-date
nginx is up-to-date
Recreating php ... done
```