# How to update existing images with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have multiple microservices and I am using docker-compose for development deployments. When there are some changes in the microservices code base, I am triggering ci job to re-deploy them. I have below script to do this. But each time I have to build all images from scratch, then run them. After all of this operation, I have `anonymous` images. So I am using the last script to remove them. What you would suggest making this process more practical? Is there any way to update an existing image without removing it with new changes?

```
- docker-compose build
- docker-compose down
- docker-compose up -d --force-recreate
- docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q) -f
```

Additional info: i am using `gitlab-ci`

Answer (score 350, accepted):

Docker containers are designed to be ephemeral. To update an existing container, you remove the old one and start a new one.
Thus the process that you are following is the correct one.

You can simplify the commands to the following ones:

```
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up --force-recreate --build -d
docker image prune -f
```

Comment: You've missed off the -d flag in the docker-compose command; is that deliberate?

Comment: I think the flag is important as not adding it will run everything in the foreground, killing off everything as soon as the session ends. Added it as many (most?) people will find `-d` useful/necessary.

Comment: This appears to be missing the `docker-compose pull` step. `--force-recreate` doesn't pull updated images; it merely recreates the containers _even if the images haven't changed._

Comment: just to make sure I understand,  so I have to rebuild the images every update and wait for it again and again?

Comment: All this did was reset my entire pi-hole to default settings and lose all my adlists, whitelists.
`docker pull pihole/pihole:latest` would have been enough.

Comment: @k4rli it sounds like you were storing all of your settings within the container itself, and not within an attached volume (which would have survived the removal of the container).  Also, `docker pull` would not upgrade your running container—you'd still need to remove and recreate the container for the pull to take effect.

Answer (score 270):

You can update it using:

```
docker-compose pull
```

Now your image is updated. If you have the previous version of container running you should restart it to use the updated image:

```
docker-compose up --detach
```

`up` command automatically recreates container on image or configuration change.

Comment: Just running this didn't update the container for me. You're missing the part to rerun it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501539/1452257 , which worked for me.

Comment: @pir I've added clarification.

Comment: restart does not work because it won't recreate the container from the pull, you have to do `down` and `up -d` again.

Comment: In my case it recreates automatically.

Comment: I think a combination of @yamenk's comment and this one are the best way to go

Comment: @EvgenBodunov "In my case it recreates automatically" This is the classic "Runs in my computer". Not very cool!

Comment: @hoo2 Do you wan't to make my answer better, please describe when container is updated from image automatically, and when it's not. I honestly don't know and can't improve the answer. "Not very cool!" is not cool itself.

Comment: Indeed, for me too, restart did not work. I had to do compose down, and up -d. Note running on centos 7.9 from official docker-ce repos.

Comment: I believe the confusion comes from the effect, that `docker-compose up` without `down` only recreates containers for images that have changed (ie. new version is available).
If you call `down` first, all containers are destroyed, therefore the `up` will recreate all of them.
If your aim is only to update containers with the newest images, than `docker-compose up -d` is enough.
If you need to recreate containers for any other reason, you need `docker-compose down` beforehand.

Answer (score 222):

I prefer to ensure  all the images are downloaded  before updating the containers with the new images to minimize the time in an intermediate state or worse being in the middle in case the download of an image fails.

1. I pull latest images:

   `docker compose pull`
2. Then I restart containers:

   `docker compose up -d --remove-orphans`
3. Optionally, I remove obsolete images:

   `docker image prune`

Comment: I like this answer, because it doesn't push to use `-f` or `--force-recreate`, which could have destructive side-effects.

Comment: Here's a simple bash script so you can run it with a single command `./update-docker-compose-services.sh`: https://pastebin.com/EdDA5hZ2

Comment: I strugged for a while trying docker-compose commands, but when I finally switched to `docker compose pull` and `docker compose up` instead then it all went smoothly.  Maybe something changed in the last two years for syntax on this answer?

Comment: @AdamNofsinger previously, "docker-compose" was a separate tool to "docker". Now, compose is part of docker so it is used as an argument to "docker"; I think most functionality should exist in the newer implementation and most commands you find online you can simply change "docker-compose" to "docker compose" and it should run as expected. YMMV

Comment: I edited the post to use the new style syntax.

Comment: @BenRandall your edit got clobbered by someone else's and reverted back to the old syntax, so I fixed it again

Answer (score 94):

```
docker-compose pull
```

then

```
docker-compose up -d
```

you don't need "down" "docker-compose up -d" command will only recreate changed one

Comment: Simple and straightforward

Comment: If you don't have any volumes its fine but if you do it will delete them. So actually it isn't an update.

Comment: @chunk1ty please quote the docs where this is described. The `up` command help explicitely says "preserving mounted volumes" (see `docker-compose up --help`). `pull` doesn't even mentions volumes at all.

Comment: Those two lines allow for partial upgrades, ie. only changed containers are stopped and upgraded.

Comment: @makeroo what is a changed container ? I do have make changes to a container service files, now i,m stuck and don,t know how to upgrade that container with that changes or reflect that changes ?

Comment: When you change the docker-compose.yml, modifying the version of the image in some container declaration, just calling "docker-compose up -d" triggers docker to stop and restart only those containers that have the version changed. It pulls new images too if needed, so you can just run "up" :-)

Answer (score 3):

With docker-compose version 3 you can add tags to your images and clean up by them depends on your logic:

```
build: ./dir
image: yourapp:tag
```

It could help you to avoid anonymous images to clean up

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed above answers, but I still insist to use the following orders to make sure everything is correct:

1. `docker-compose pull`
2. `docker-compose down`
3. `docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 2):

There is also a script, with which one can update many docker-compose stacks at once.

It is called [compose-update](https://github.com/FrederikRogalski/compose-update) and can be found at the following link:

https://github.com/FrederikRogalski/compose-update

## **compose-update** a docker-compose-image-updater

This python script updates the images of one or many docker-compose stacks automatically.

If multiple docker-compose directories are supplied, the script updates them in parallel.

### Demo

[image: output]

### Usage

```
Usage: compose-update [OPTIONS] [UPDATE_DIRS]...

  Update docker-compose images automatically.

  Takes one or more directorys as input and searches for a
  compose file in one of the following forms:
  "compose.yaml", "compose.yml", "docker-compose.yaml",
  "docker-compose.yml"

Options:
  --prune / --no-prune  Prune docker images after update
                        process if set
  --help                Show this message and exit.
```

### Installation

```
git clone https://github.com/FrederikRogalski/compose-update.git
cd compose-updater
chmod +x update-compose
```

Then add the file 'update-compose' to your path.

Answer (score 0):

A useful note for Synology users: if you are using the Container Manager, then be sure to include the project name when you call the `up` command.

This is what my update script looks like (I run it manually):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sudo docker-compose pull
sudo docker-compose -p <name> up -d
sudo docker image prune -f
```

Replace `<name>` with the project name that you use in Container Manager.