# Docker file installing wrong php

Tags: php, linux, docker, ubuntu, version

I have a laravel/php docker image that I updated to PHP 8.1 - I am now trying to go back to our project version 7.3 and won't work.

here's my YAML

```
###############################################################################
#                          Generated on forwardforce.io                          #
###############################################################################
version: "3.1"
services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.1-alpine
    container_name: mtn-postgres
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
    - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    - .:/application
    ports:
    - 5001:5432
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=root
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
    - POSTGRES_DB=forge

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: mtn-webserver
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
    - .:/application
    - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
    - "8091:80"
    tty: true

  php-fpm:
    build: phpdocker/php-fpm
    container_name: mtn-php-fpm
    working_dir: /application
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=docker.for.mac.host.internal"
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=MTN-Docker"
    image: php:7.2-alpine
    volumes:
    - .:/application
    - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini

volumes:
    db:
```

and here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR "/application"

# Fix debconf warnings upon build
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install git
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install libpng-dev \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

# Install selected extensions and other stuff
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install  php7.2-pgsql php7.2-gd php-xdebug php-ssh2 \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

# Install git
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install git \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

# Install php-imagick
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install php-imagick \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

# Install Node.js, Yarn and required dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y curl gnupg build-essential \
  && curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - \
  && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
  && apt-get remove -y --purge cmdtest \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn \
  # remove useless files from the current layer
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists.d/* \
  && apt-get autoremove \
  && apt-get clean \
  && apt-get autoclean

RUN npm install -g cordova ionic
RUN npm i -D -E -g @angular/cli
```

I have deleted docker cache & containers and ran:
`docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build`

But I do see "59bf1c3509f3 Already exists " in the build while it's running. And after it's finished I have the latest version of PHP 8.13

So could it be a different cache somewhere else I am not clearing? Or how can I force install of PHP 7.2 o 7.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update existing images with docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316462/how-to-update-existing-images-with-docker-compose)

Answer (score 0):

`apt` is the package manager for Debian based distribution. Use `apk` to manage software packages on Alpine Linux. See [How to use this image](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/).