# How to restart a container with every interval timeout in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How to restart a container with every interval timeout in `docker-compose.yml` by an option?

This is my simplified `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  ivms_app:
      build: .
      image: an_image
      container_name: app_name
      restart: unless-stopped

      ports:
        - "9001:9001"
```

I have set the `restart` option with `unless-stopped` attribute. But I want an option for restarting a container with every interval timeout in `docker-compose.yml` like this:

`interval_restart: 30  # 30 minutes`

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this kind of configuration in the `docker-compose.yml` file. Have you tried anything else? For example a `cron` job which will run a script every 30 minutes that does what you want? Related: [How to restart a single container with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466428/how-to-restart-a-single-container-with-docker-compose).

Comment: I'm curious that under what context do you want to have this behavior?

Comment: This question seems similar to what is being asked here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1003348/set-time-period-to-restart-a-container-with-docker-compose, the answer might be what you are looking for @Benyamin Jafari.

Comment: @PrabhatikaVij Thanks for mentioning the link. I don't know how I solved the problem in 2018 :-D. The mentioned post was written in 2020 that's why I hadn't seen that. So sounds great for others' issue

Comment: if you are looking for a way to tune the delay between restart attempts, see [restart_policy in Docker Compose specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart_policy).

Comment: @dragon at that time (2018) I was looking for an attribute in docker-compose to restart a container every X minutes! BTW, thank you for sharing about the restart policy in docker compose I didn't know about that. :-D