# Can we replace an image with docker-compose while container is running

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working at a micro-service application and there are multiple services. I am using docker-compose to run instances of different micro services. We create an image for every micro service. If I change the code of a micro-service, I use 'docker-compose down' then changing the version of updated micro service and then use 'docker-compose up'. I think, there should be a way to update the image at run time without using 'docker-compose down' and 'docker-compose up'.

Is there and way to replace image of running container with docker-compose?

Comment: I think, this could help you. [Upgrade docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734402/how-to-upgrade-docker-container-after-its-image-changed) and [docker compose in production](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/#deploying-changes).

Comment: Have you tried Kubernetes?

Answer (score 3):

You can skip `docker-compose down`. The `docker-compose up` command will recreate the container if the image has been built or pulled since it was last started. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501539/596285) for more details and an example of this in action.

You cannot hot swap the image from within a running container. That's equivalent to replacing the root hard drive while a Linux OS is running. It would break things, particularly anything with an open file handle.

Comment: Kubernetes could do it, so how about Docker swarm..?

Comment: @jtlz2 Kubernetes doesn't do it, it replaces the containers, same as docker-compose and Swarm Mode. Look at how ReplicaSet and Deployment are used to perform a rolling update.