# how to restart docker container using docker-compose on container failure

Tags: docker-compose

I have a server that runs earlier than a postgresql and I read that docker-compose v3 no longer honors `depends_on` using healthchecks.  I was wondering what other options I have outside of something like `wait-for`.  That is, I would like for docker-compose to restart containers that close/shutdown after failure. I found this thread which shows how to restart a container with docker-compose [How to restart a single container with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466428/how-to-restart-a-single-container-with-docker-compose) but that doesn't address my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart_policy)