# Updating a container created from a custom dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-image

Before anything, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734402/how-to-upgrade-docker-container-after-its-image-changed) question and the related links in it, but I am still confused about how to resolve this on my setup.

I wrote my own docker file to install Archiva, which is very similar to [this](https://github.com/dfranssen/docker-archiva/blob/master/Dockerfile) file. I created an image from the docker file using `docker build -t archiva .` and have a container which I run using `docker run archiva`. As seen in the docker file, the user data that I want to preserve is in a `volume`.

Now I want to upgrade to Archive 2.2.0. How can I update my container, so that the user-data thats in the volume is preserved? If I change the docker file by h=just changing the version number, and run the `docker build` again, it will just create another container.

Comment: Coud you post the command you use to run the docker image? If you used `docker run -v` to mount a host folder to the volume location, then you can reuse that host folder with your new container and data will be preserved. BTW for the terminology, `docker build` create a new "image", while `docker run` create a new "container" based on the image.

Comment: I don't use the `-v` flag in the run command, but I have it declared in the docker file itself. So I need to take it out of the docker file then? I thought form reading the documentation that it was either-or i.e. either put it in the docker file or use it with the `-v` flag.

Comment: I think it is possible to use `docker run --volumes-from old_container new_image` to preserve the data.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I do create a new container, and just use the data from the old container?

Comment: Yes I think that should work. Always make a backup first if your old container has important data.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll have to go with that! Thanks. I'll keep this question up to see if anyone has any other suggestions.

Comment: Why not just run the commands to update your service in your current container? Using `docker exec -it CONT_NAME bash`? From your use case, it doesn't sound like you need a new container....

Comment: Doing updates from inside container is supposed to be a bad practice! Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

### Best practice

The option `--volume` of the `docker-run` enables sharing files between host and container(s) and especially preserve consistent [user] data.

### The problem is ..

.. it appears that you are not using `--volume` and that the user data are in the image. (and that's a bad practice beacuse it leads to the situation you are in: unable to upgrade a service easily.

### One solution (the best IMO) is

#### Back-up the user data

To use the command `docker-cp`: "`Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem.`"

> `docker cp [--help] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH`

#### Upgrade your `Dockerfile`

By editing your `Dockerfile` and changing the version.

#### Use the `--volume` option

Use `docker run -v /host/path/user-data:container/path/user-data archiva`

And you're good!