# How to properly update Wordpress on docker

Tags: wordpress, docker

Like in the title I am looking for properly approach to updating WordPress which is set up on docker. When I updating the application without changing the image, I never exactly know if the application-version matches the version given by the docker-image.

Should I first update my image version in compose file, and then manually update Wordpress form admin panel? Because Wordpress same as the database will not update automatically by changing the compose file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrade docker container after its image changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734402/how-to-upgrade-docker-container-after-its-image-changed)