# How to update the application running in the docker container? (for example, spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to figure out the docker for the hundredth time. Now I create `spring-boot` simple application and create `docker image` for it:

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /build/libs/hello-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar hello-docker.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "hello-docker.jar"]
```

What did i do step by step:

1) Build my app(as a result, my `hello-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` appeared in the `build` folder)

2) moved to the directory where the `Docker file` is located and executed the command: `docker build -f Dockerfile -t springdocker .`

3) Run this `image` as container: `docker run -p 8080:8080 springdocker`

As a result, my application started successfully.

But now I decided to change something in my application. I did it and tried to repeat all the steps. `1-> 2-> error`

On 2 stepa new image was created and the old one was in the active state. It turns out that I need to stop the old one and start a new one.

it is not comfortable. I intuitively understand that this is not how it should work. I do not understand how to properly update the container. I constantly change my application and if I need to stop the container then create an image and then launch it - this is not a convenience but a complication. With the same success, I can stop the my application and launch a new one without a docker. I understand that I do not understand how this works, and I want someone to explain to me how to do it.

Comment: How about using `docker exec`?

Comment: The setup you describe `docker stop; docker rm; docker build; docker run` is absolutely the standard "iterate developing for Docker" sequence.  I would develop your application normally using your host's JVM, and look into Docker mostly as a fairly late-stage packaging/deployment solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use docker-compose, this will save you a lot of time.

Just write a docker-compose.yml file in the same folder as Dockerfile:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  yourapplication:
    build: . -> this is the location of your dockerfile
    image: yourapplication_imagename
    container_name: yourapplication_containername
    ports:
       - "8080:8080"
    tty: true
```

And, to update the application you only have to run:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache yourapplication
docker-compose up -d
```

This will recreate the image and replace the container with your updated app.

Without docker-compose: you already have a good thread about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734402/how-to-upgrade-docker-container-after-its-image-changed)

Answer (score 0):

You should automate your build process. If the desired result of this process is a docker image, your automated build process should not stop after creating the .jar

Fortunately, there is a good tutorial for building a Docker image for running a Spring Boot application using different build tools (Maven, Gradle):
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

In the end, you will be able to deploy your application to a docker image using just

```
./mvnw install dockerfile:build
```