# docker - mysql Version - How to update?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I `have no knowledge of docker and its inner workings`.

I have a docker image of an application which support has installed on my Linux Desktop.
Current version of `mySql when queried through docker prompt is 5.5.6`

I updated mysql on my desktop to 5.7.x but still inside docker prompt its showing 5.5.6 ..
Can anyone help me out ?
Output --

```
dockerdev@localhost:~$ ps -aef | grep mysql
root        31    28  0 14:45 ?        00:00:00 runsv mysql
root        40    34  0 14:45 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql      471    40  0 14:45 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306

dockerdev@localhost:~$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.62, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

I run the docker container

```
docker-compose -f ./application.yml up -d
```

application.yml

```
---
myapp:
  image: docker.xyz.com/myapp:latest
  container_name: myapp
  hostname: localhost
  ports:
    - "80:80"       # Apache
    - "8000:8000"   # Tomcat
    - "3306:3306"   # Mysql    
  environment: ....
  links: ....
  volumes: 
    # MySQL Data
    - /home/kunal/alpha/containers/beta/gamma/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql/
```

Comment: From your description. You have two different versions, right? Your host (PC,laptop) and a docker container, is that right?

Comment: @abestrad thats correct

Comment: So, they are living in different worlds, any changes to the host won't affect the containers version, if you want to upgrade or use a different version in your container(s),  you have to pull and run the mysql version from the registry.

Comment: I am not getting instructions to upgrade - I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734402/how-to-upgrade-docker-container-after-its-image-changed but to no avail.

Comment: I did - 1) docker pull mysql:5.6
( 2) docker rm -f  <application-name>  (3) docker run --name app_db --restart unless-stopped \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root123 \
-d mysql:5.6

Comment: Now when i run docker-compose application.yml - it throws an error name used elsewhere

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How is this problem even related to programming?

Comment: @NicoHaase having a generic comments like the one you posted does not help. This problem was posted almost 3 years ago - this is a valid question on Docker - and is still valid today. In the aspect of programming then - would u deny all question that are apache webserver or mysql etc

Comment: "would u deny all question that are apache webserver or mysql etc" - yes, of course. These belong to serverfault.com or superuser.com, unless they are **directly** related to programming