# How can i restart my website and apply new changes to a docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, web, server

I want to restart my docker container to apply new changes made. I dont want to create a new image each time i make changes rather that it will overwrite the old one and then restart the container using the rewritten one.

I have tried stopping the container, then building an image with the same name as the old one. i then write `docker -compose up -d`. Problem is this creates a new container called like -web

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734402/how-to-upgrade-docker-container-after-its-image-changed ?

Comment: why you don't want to create a new image, if data is related, You can mount data to a volume, and creating a new image will make no changes for the user or for you, just apply a new configuration.
maybe [this](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) can be helpful, And @WandererAboveTheSea link should be helpful as well, Thats exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach is to build a new image, stop the existing server container, and then start a new container based on a new image.  If you're using Docker Compose, this can be as little as

```bash
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

Compare this to running a server in a compiled language like Java or Go.  Here you have the exact same workflow: compile your updated sources into a new jar file or binary, stop the existing server, and start a new one.  There's not usually a reason to try to preserve the existing process and update it with new code.

In the same way, a container is a (temporary) wrapper around a single (temporary) process.  There's no particular reason that you need the same container; in normal operation you should be able to delete and recreate a container without losing anything.  In Docker you need to recreate a container fairly routinely to change various startup-time-only options, and also to update the underlying image.  If you move on to clustered environments like Kubernetes this becomes even more important: you'll have multiple replicas of a container so they can't have persistent state, and it's possible for a container to be deleted and recreated outside of your immediate control.

Comment: I figuered it was just better to link volumes and then just restart the docker container. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Volumes are for keeping persistent _data_; your _code_ generally belongs in an immutable image.  In either case, again, there's nothing especially valuable about the container that you can't delete and recreate it.