# How to setup docker architecture

Tags: postgresql, nginx, deployment, docker

I'd like to have the following configuration:

```
               Docker Containers   

||||||||||||      ||||||||||||      ||||||||||||
|          |      |          |      |          |
|          |      |          |      |          |
|          | <--> |          | <--> |          |
|          |      |          |      |          |
|          |      |          |      |          |
||||||||||||      ||||||||||||      ||||||||||||
   nginx           web server         postgres
```

With the following setup:

1. Nginx

   - change `nginx.conf`
   - add an appropriate `sites-available` entry
   - link config `sites-enabled`
2. PostgreSQL

   - setup user login and password
3. Web Server

   - clone from repository
   - build release version
   - run server process

I have a couple of questions as well:

a) how to pass *secrets* to Docker like API keys, passwords and so on?

b) is this possible to clone repo from docker or there is other way to do that?

c) how and where deploy such applications?

d) is that setup even possible?

Answer (score 4):

This setup is very common with docker. I'd recommend you look into using docker-compose ([example](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/)) because it makes setting it up drastically easier.

Passing in secrets is done through environment variables at docker run time. If you have many you can store them in an env-file.

Yes, you can clone a repo from a docker container or during a docker build. Cloning a private repo during a docker build is currently not feasible (without exposing your credentials) so it's usually recommended to clone your repo before running docker build.

Comment: This it exactly the tutorial I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

a) usually pass *secrets* through environment variables, this is easy for containers to use.

b) yes, you can, if you want clone a public repo, you can do it in Dockerfile with `RUN git clone repo`; also you can pull you repo at `Entrypoint` if you want make sure your repo is updated.

c) emm...I don't know how to answer this, maybe [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com)?

d) this setup is possible, but here is some advices:

- you can try using [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) which is easier to make reserve proxy to your web server container.
- using `Volume` to serve your web contents, so you can bind volume to nginx container and serve your static contents with nginx.
- build a data only container for your database, you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652410/2382404)

Answer (score 0):

This is piece of cake with Docker and Docker-Compose. All you need are suitable containers where you can pass the parameters on startup. Afterwards the compose-template can be moved around and instanced multiple times.

The containers communicate through links and docker provides hostnames for handling changing ip addresses.

This is an example for setting up the Jira web application with a postgres database. This should be analogous to your example. An nginx server can be added as easily.

```
jira:
  image: blacklabelops/jira
  ports:
    - '8100:8080'
  volumes:
    - /opt/atlassian-home
  environment:
    - 'DATABASE_URL=postgresql://jiradb@postgresql/jiradb'
    - 'DB_PASSWORD=jellyfish'
  links:
    - postgresql
postgresql:
  image: sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-1
  ports:
    - '5432:5432'
  environment:
    - 'PSQL_TRUST_LOCALNET=true'
    - 'DB_USER=jiradb'
    - 'DB_PASS=jellyfish'
    - 'DB_NAME=jiradb'
```

> The Jira server will be available with localhost:8100 and the database will be available with localhost:5432

Comment: Do i need to use `ports:`? I saw some examples where it's not necessary (even for Postgres image). I don't want to store `ENV`s in my `Dockerfile`. How to configure postgres or nginx image instead of using a defaut one?

Comment: You do not need port declaration when the conversation is only required along the links and the installed service all already know which ports to bind or they run on default ports. Working without ENVs is unknown to me because they enable flexibility in reusing the image and keep my credentials out of sight.