# How to save my databases between restart mysql in Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I've run mysql in Docker (Docker for Windows 1.12.6, not docker toolbox) with command

```
docker run --name mysqldb -v /d/databases/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d -p 3306:3306 mysql:5.7
```

And when I've done it first time everything was great. How I've docker container with mysql and database directory on host machine mount as docker container volume.

But when I try to start container agan with command `docker start mysqldb` I have error **Error response from daemon: mkdir /d: file exists
Error: failed to start containers: mysqldb**

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to save my databases between container and docker restart?

**UPD**
This is out of `docker ps -a`

```
3b5b6cb91107        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.sh"   9 hours ago         Up 15 seconds       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   mysqldb
```

Container has been started but volume `/var/lib/mysql` is no longer mount to host directory.

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Source": "/d/databases/mysql",
        "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
],
```

Comment: Can you perform `docker ps -a` to verify the mysql container isn't running anymore and check it logs: `docker logs container-id`

Comment: mysql container isn't running anymore and check it log has no errors. The problem is something else

Comment: Does this answer your question? [retain the data inside database using docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309961/retain-the-data-inside-database-using-docker)

Answer (score 1):

This is little strange because i executed the same command with my database container and it is working fine everytime.

```
docker run --name main-database -e DB_HOST=asas -e DB_PORT=testing -p 3306 -v /home/mahesh/projects/django/tmp/mysql:/var/lib/mysql main/database
```

Could you please upload the output of :

```
docker ps -a
```

And please check if the container is in exited state.

**UPDATE** :
What i can see is your container is up now

I think you should start fresh:

Please stop the container using `docker stop container-id`

Then remove it `docker rm container-id`

Delete the image if exists `docker rmi image-id`

Now run your command with `--rm` flag

```
docker run --rm --name mysqldb -v /somedir_in_your_home/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d -p 3306:3306 mysql:5.7
```

Comment: I've added out of `docker ps -a` to question