# Persisting database using docker volumes

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to persist postgres data in a docker container so that as soon as you `docker-compose down and docker-compose up -d` you don't lose data from your previous session. I haven't been able to make it do much of anything - pulling the container down and back up again routinely deletes the data.

Here's my current docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8245:8245'
    volumes:
      - .:/home/app/api
      - /home/app/api/node_modules
      - /home/app/api/public/src/bower_components
    links:
      - db
  db:
    build: ./database
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - '8246:5432'
    volumes_from:
      - dbdata

  dbdata:
    image: "postgres:9.5.2"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Help?

Answer (score 9):

According to the [Dockment of Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/volumes-volumedriver), when you write something like:

```
volumes:
  - /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

It creates a new docker volume and map it to `/var/lib/postgresql/data` inside the container.
Therefore, each time you run `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose down`, it creates new volume. You can confirm the behavior with `docker volume ls`.

To avoid it, you have two options:

**(A) Map host directory into container**

You can map directory of host into container using `<HOST_PATH>:<CONTAINER_PATH>`.

```
volumes:
  - /path/to/your/host/directory:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

The data of postgresql will be saved into `/path/to/your/host/directory` of the container host.

**(B) Use external container**

docker-compose has an option of [external container](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external).
When it is set to true, it won't always create volume.
Here's an example.

```
version: '2'
services:
  dbdata:
    image: postgres:9.5.2
    volumes:
      - mypostgresdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  mypostgresdb:
    external: true
```

With `external: true`, docker-compose won't create the `mypostgredb` volume, so you have to create it by your own using following command:

```sh
docker volume create --name=mypostgredb
```

The data of postgresql will be saved into docker volume named `mypostgredb`. Read [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) for more detail.

Comment: 0

I tried this, but it does not work for me. I get still the same issue as OP. If I do docker volume ls I can see the previous volumes of data there, but the current one it has empty data