# How to copy and use existing postgres data folder into docker postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to build postgres docker container for testing some issue.
I have:

1. Archived folder of postgres files(`/var/lib/postgres/data/`)
2. Dockerfile that place folder into doccker postgres:latest.

I want:

1. Docker image that reset self-state after recreate image.
2. Container that have database state based on passed into the container postgres files
3. I don't want to wait for a long time operation of backup and restore existing database in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` initialization script.
4. I DON'T WANT TO USE VOLUMES because I don't need to store new data between restart (That's why this post is different from [How to use a PostgreSQL container with existing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679995/how-to-use-a-postgresql-container-with-existing-data). In that post volumes are used)

My suggestion is to copy postgres files(`/var/lib/postgres/data/`) from host machine into docker's `/var/lib/postgres/data/` in build phase.

But postgres docker replace this files when initdb phase is executing.

How to ask Postgres docker not overriding database files?

e.g.
Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:latest


COPY ./postgres-data.tar.gz /opt/pg-data/
WORKDIR /opt/pg-data
RUN tar -xzf postgres-data.tar.gz
RUN mv ./data/ /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg-data/
```

Run command

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg-data --name database-immage1 database-docker
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a PostgreSQL container with existing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679995/how-to-use-a-postgresql-container-with-existing-data)

Comment: It is not the same as the previous post link. In that post they use a) volumes b) make dump of db and c) restore from dump. I don't want that step because is tedious for 30 database with its own user and make dump it is not so fast. I have an archive with database directory and I have to replace it inside the docker. 
They restore dump when image running, I have to restore dump when container build because  I don't have to spend much time until database restore every time when I am restoring the container

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't really need to create a custom image with the database snapshot you could use volumes. Un-tar the database files somewhere on the host say `~/pgdata` then run the image. Example:

```
docker run -v ~/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ -p 5432:5432 postgres:9.5
```

The files must be compatible with the `postgres` version of the image so use the same image version as the archived database.

If, instead, you must recreate the image you don't need to uncompress the database archive. The [`ADD`](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-2-the-difference-between-copy-and-add-in-a-dockerile) instruction will do 
that for you. Make sure the tar does not contain any leading directory.

The `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM postgres:latest
ADD ./postgres-data.tar.gz /var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

Build it:

```
docker build . -t database-docker
```

Run without overriding the environment variable `PGDATA`. Note that you copy the files in `/var/lib/postgresql/data` but the `PGDATA` points to `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg-data`.

Run the container:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 --name  database-image1 database-docker
```

Comment: As I write in question I don't want to use volume. I want to leave all extra data after I recreate the image