# Docker-Compose postgres upgrade initdb: error: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I had postgres 11 installed using docker-compose. I wanted to upgrade it to 12 but even though I have removed the container and its volume but the status of the container says "Restarting".

Here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
    ports:
    - "5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - /etc/postgresql/12/postgresql.conf:/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
    - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  db_data:
```

However it is not working and the logs has the following issue

```
2020-07-02T12:54:47.012973448Z The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
2020-07-02T12:54:47.013030445Z This user must also own the server process.
2020-07-02T12:54:47.013068962Z 
2020-07-02T12:54:47.013222608Z The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
2020-07-02T12:54:47.013261425Z The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
2020-07-02T12:54:47.013281815Z The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
2020-07-02T12:54:47.013293326Z 
2020-07-02T12:54:47.013303793Z Data page checksums are disabled.
2020-07-02T12:54:47.013313919Z 
2020-07-02T12:54:47.013450079Z initdb: error: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
2020-07-02T12:54:47.013487706Z If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
2020-07-02T12:54:47.013501126Z the directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" or run initdb
2020-07-02T12:54:47.013512379Z with an argument other than "/var/lib/postgresql/data".
```

How could I remove or empty this /var/lib/postgresql/data when the container is constantly restarting?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Upgrading from Postgres 11 --> 12 is a major upgrade and you can't just substitute one for the other. If the 11 instance has data associated with it you will need to install the 12 instance in another location and either do a dump/restore or use pg_upgrade.

Comment: Future users:  Please check for misconfigurations too. For me, it was a typo in yml file.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679995/how-to-use-a-postgresql-container-with-existing-data

Answer (score 38):

Quoting [@yosifkit](https://github.com/yosifkit) from [this issue](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/263)

> The volume needs to be empty or a valid already initialized postgres
> database with the file `PG_VERSION` in there so the init can be
> skipped.
>
> ... If there are any files or folders in there like `lost+found` it
> will probably fail to initialize. If there are files that you want to
> keep in the volume (or have no control over) you could adjust the
> `PGDATA` environment variable to point to a sub-directory in there
> like `-e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/db-files/`.

So I added `PGDATA` to the `environment` section of the compose file to solve the issue (notice the `some_name` at the end):

```yaml
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/some_name/
```

Comment: in my case, add PG_DATA (erasing old data, mybe you have some backups to restore), then next time it restarts, it restarts OK.

Comment: Thank you! I struggled with this for a long time but adding PG_data worked for me as well

Answer (score 18):

I got this issue because the `/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf` and the `/var/lib/postgresql/data` overlap in the docker container at `/var/lib/postgresql/`.

**An example of a broken config is:**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:10"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgresql.conf:/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
      - ./pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

**To avoid this I tell PostgreSQL to find it's config in `/etc/postgresql.conf` instead so the overlapping volumes don't occur like this:**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:10"
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql.conf"]
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql.conf
      - ./pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

This is similar to what [pmsoltani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5863877/pmsoltani) suggests, but I move the location of the `postgresql.conf` file instead of the data directory.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today, I fixed it by removing the content of the volume db_data in your case

```
docker volume ls
docker volume inspect db_data <-- will show you the mountpoint
```

I went to the directory (mountpoint) ex: /path/data

```
cp data data.backup
cd data
rm -R *
```

And start services:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: CAUTION when you run `rm -R *`.  ⚠️
This deletes all your files in the folder you run the command at.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by providing a sub path

```
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: some-name
          subPath: data
```

Comment: This solution fix my issue on 1.27.8-gke cluster.

Answer (score 1):

It pops up as the first search result without approved answer, so let me add my solution here.

I want to provide custom `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` in `/var/lib/postgresql/data` where the files are stored by default in image `postgres:latest` (PostgreSQL 15 as of the time of writing).

There is a directory provided by the image where you can store `.sql` or `.sh` files to initialize the database: `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`.

I `COPY` crafted `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` files to `/tmp` and `COPY` a short Bash script that will move the configuration files into `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. It ensures proper order of invocation: first `initdb`, and then replacement of config files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was when I **runned in Windows PowerShell from directory with russian and other spesific sumbols**:

> PS C:\Install\Конфигурация камунда + постгря\PostgreSQL>
> docker-compose up -d

The problem disapiared when I run the same from another dirictory with usual and latin symbols.

Answer (score -8):

Edit: Just use this for development environment, otherwise you will lose your data.

Another solution is to simply remove the volume attached to the container:

```bash
docker-compose down -v
```

Comment: And lost all data.

Comment: Of course this comment was for a dev environment. If you're running postgres in a container in production and don't expect the machine to be shutdown for any reason, I fear you have a bigger problem to solve :)