# Store Data from Docker container to Local Machine

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

My Question is if I use a docker container (say [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)) and have a named volume created to store the data from container to local [as implied here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679995/how-to-use-a-postgresql-container-with-existing-data) (any many more articles and forums). The data remains as long as the volume is up, even if I stop the container or even remove the image. But if I remove the volume it self the entire data is wiped clean. Is it possible to prevent this? if yes, how? also is it possible to take the back up of `/var/lib/postgresql/data` from container to local without it being effected by volume removal?

Comment: You can use a mount, to mount a local directory. Your data would then be written to the host directly.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this?