# How can I use VOLUME in a Dockerfile to persist individual files in a directory?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This application I'm trying to Dockerize has configuration files in the root of the install dir. If I use `VOLUME` to mount the install dir on the host, I'll end up with the application on the host, too. I only want to store the configuration files on the host.

Should I use hard links in the container and use VOLUME to mount the dir that has the hardlinks? Do hard links even work in a container?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with persistent storage (e.g. databases) in docker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496940/how-to-deal-with-persistent-storage-e-g-databases-in-docker)

Answer (score 2):

You can mount individual files. Below is from the docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

> Mount a host file as a data volume
>
> The -v flag can also be used to mount a single file - instead of just
>   directories - from the host machine.
>
> ```
> $ docker run --rm -it -v ~/.bash_history:/root/.bash_history ubuntu /bin/bash
> ```
>
> This will drop you into a bash shell in a new container, you will have
>   your bash history from the host and when you exit the container, the
>   host will have the history of the commands typed while in the
>   container.
>
> Note: Many tools used to edit files including vi and sed --in-place may result in an inode change. Since Docker v1.1.0, this will produce an error such as “sed: cannot rename ./sedKdJ9Dy: Device
>   or resource busy”. In the case where you want to edit the mounted
>   file, it is often easiest to instead mount the parent directory.