# Strategy for arangodb data backup in docker container

Tags: docker, arangodb, arangojs

I would like to do a backup of arangodb data in case of arangodb runs in a docker container. (the data of arangodb are mounted as volume to the host system).

One solution would be to create a docker image (based on the official arangodb image) which contains a script for the backup via **arangodump**
But the question is who triggers the backup (e.g. enhance the image with cron or trigger the script execution from the outside via cron )

A solution would also be when I would be able to do the backup via arangojs (because of using it for my node server). But it seems there is no API for this...

Can anybody of you has a solution or suggestions to this topic?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496940/how-to-deal-with-persistent-storage-e-g-databases-in-docker ? see also https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/  and https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/ and https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/

Comment: My question is not about volumes (which I already use) but about a strategy  how to trigger a backup (e.g. via cron or else) ....

Comment: Did ou solved your issue ? I have the same question. For now i think i will execute arangodump from the outside using cron

Comment: Yes in my docker image I have a script which uses arangodump for exporting. Then I create a zip file and upload it to AWS S3. The trigger for this comes form a cron job...