# Restore Backup into local ArangoDB

Tags: docker, arangodb

I have a problem. I am using `ArangoDB Enterprise - 3.8.6` via Docker. I downloaded a Backup from another `ArangoDB`. How can I upload these files/backup to my local ArangoDB that runs on Docker, so that my ArangoDB have the files.

The picture below shows what my backup looks like

[image]

I already read the documentation but I do not find any helpful information https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangorestore-examples.html and [Strategy for arangodb data backup in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395616/strategy-for-arangodb-data-backup-in-docker-container)

Inside Docker Desktop I started  `CLI` and wrote down `arangorestore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you downloaded is not a backup unfortunately, but the file system directory. Please perform `arangodump` on your first instance, which you can then easily restore via `arangorestore`.

I take it that you would like a full backup and restore, something like this:

```
arangodump --server.endpoint <source> --server.username <username> --server.password <password> --all-databases true
```

followed by

```
arangorestore --server.endpoint <target> --server.username <username> --server.password <password> --all-databases true
```

No need to get inside the docker container, so to speak.