# Docker image container - where can I store my files?

Tags: php, sql, docker, webserver

I have created a docker image container which is running on a virtual machine (with docker toolbox). My Problem is now that I don't know in which windows path I can store my files for the development? Also I'm not sure how I can open this image container in the browser (docker-machine ip)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to define a data volume. In short you declare a volume in your Dockerfile thus declaring that this path in your container will essentially be bound to a path on your host (that'd be your VM if I understand the setup correctly). E.g. (say that you want your shared path to live in /var/www in your container, then you add something like next command in your in your Dockerfile):

`VOLUME ["/var/www"]`

Then upon spinning up your container you bound it to your host's path:
E.g. (say your code lives in /src/webapp in your VM): 

`docker run -v /src/webapp:/var/www`

While you are at it you may want to consider fitting your setup to the 'data volume' pattern (in short having another container playing the part of a shareable data volume) which is generally considered best practice for working with persistent data in Docker.

See docker documentation for details:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/
and this thread
[How to deal with persistent storage (e.g. databases) in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496940/how-to-deal-with-persistent-storage-e-g-databases-in-docker) for more on the 'data volume' pattern.