# How can I keep ALL changes made to a docker container?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, docker-container, docker-image

I'm using docker as a "light" virtual machine. For example, when I need to do some experiments on Ubuntu and don't want to mess up the host OS, I simply run `docker run -it ubuntu bash`.

Generally I'm very happy with it, except that I cannot keep the changes after I `exit`, which means I need to rerun

```
apt update && apt install vim git python python3 <other_tools> && pip install flask coverage <other_libraries> && .....
```

every single time I start the docker container as a VM, which is very inefficient.

I've noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496940/how-to-deal-with-persistent-storage-e-g-databases-in-docker?rq=1), but it only enables me to keep some specific *files* from being erased, whereas I want *the whole system* (including but not limited to all configuration, cache and tools installed) to be retained between the life cycles of the docker container.

Answer (score 1):

You must use  something like

`docker commit mycontainer_id myuser/myimage:12`

see the doc: [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/)

and then you launch your saved image myuser/myimage:12

But you should definitely use a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

Comment: The Dockerfile sounds powerful... but very complicated :/