# How to specify source when creating a docker volume

Tags: docker

According, to the docker documentation a volume can be created like this?

```
docker volume create myvol
```

is there a way to specify the source directory?

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of Docker volumes: bind mount and named. A bind mount is done at runtime, and it's the one you're thinking about when you're talking about a source directory. It looks like this:

`docker run -v /mydir:/app someimage`

This would mount the `/mydir` directory on your host machine to `/app` in the running container.

A named volume doesn't have a source directory, it exists in the container space only. It's typically used to preserve data between container runs, because containers are ephemeral.

A common use case would be preserving the packages from an `npm install`, `pip install` or some other package manager for development. I may not want to re-download 100 packages every time I run my container. Instead, I could use a volume to persist them between runs:

`docker run -v myvol:/app/node_modules someimage`

The next time I start this container and mount `myvol` like this, myvol already has all of the installed packages from last time in `/app/node_modules`, so npm will simply scan over them quickly for updates and move along.

Also consider a named volume in the role of running a Dockerized database. Check this SO post, it has a very good answer: [How to deal with persistent storage (e.g. databases) in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496940/how-to-deal-with-persistent-storage-e-g-databases-in-docker)

Edit: bind mounts must start with a backslash for the host_src, otherwise `docker run` creates a named volume.

Comment: Would '-v' work in docker swarm? I've tried but does not work

Comment: That I don't know, I haven't used Docker Swarm. Kubernetes and AWS ECS both support volumes, I have to think Swarm does as well.

Comment: @bluescores Do you know how indicate the name of the volume when running `docker run -v mydir:/app someimage` because otherwise it creates a random number

Comment: @Arturo is helping me see I made a mistake. Bind mounts must start with a backslash, otherwise `docker run` will create a named volume with whatever name is given. I will edit my response. Thanks!