# Designing system architecture with Docker containers

Tags: mongodb, docker, ravendb

I am  new to Docker. I want some opinion from some expert about container design. I have set up a database in **the MongoDB cloud (Atlas)**. I have Windows app in Docker container which include Windows OS and application based components. I want to use **RavenDB** and this database is very new to me. A component of my Windows container will communicate to both **MongoDB** and **RavenDB**.
My question is
should I create different docker container for **RavenDB** or will I install **RavenDB** in my existing windows container.
it is design decision problem. I am new to **RavenDB** and **Docker** so the pros and cons are not clear to me yet. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar application, where I had a postgresql db and Nodejs webapp. 
The web application and the database were running on separate docker containers.

- This way the two containers were independent of each other.
- This replicates the actual production scenario, where you'll have your service and database running separately.
- It is recommended to run single process on each container.
- Better modularity of the services. Separation of Concerns.
- Scaling containers horizontally is much easier if the container is isolated to a single function.

This way the two containers were independent of each other. The postgresql db container had a volume mounted to persist the data.

A more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/451)

Comment: thanks  for your reply @Gokul Chandrasekaran. i have another question to ask. if a container size overflown, will my db' s data wiped out? how could i  manage this special case .

Comment: This post should help understand better how volumes are mounted to enable persistent storage for containers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496940/how-to-deal-with-persistent-storage-e-g-databases-in-docker