# How to make docker containerized api's connect to database in local host

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, fastapi

I have a project to deploy that has two fastapi containers and a mariadb database container. It turns out that the database container was a bad idea because we cannot modify anything without wiping out all the data inside. I want to change the mariadb database from running inside a container to running in the local host, which is a Ubuntu machine. I'm confused on how I need to modify my docker compose file, as while I have seen some examples of people running it on the terminal with the `docker run` command and the flag `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway`, I am not seeing how to adapt that to my case.

Here is the current docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.5
    network_mode: "host"
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443" 
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=myemail@mydomain.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    labels:
      - 'traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=443'
      
  mariadb:
    build:
      context: ./MariaDB/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mydbpassword
    container_name: mariadb
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=false'

  fastapi-api1:
    build:
      context: ./API1/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./files_user:/files"
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.fastapi-api1.rule=Host(`ap1.mydomain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.fastapi-api1.entrypoints=websecure'
      - "traefik.http.routers.fastapi-api1.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - 'traefik.http.routers.fastapi-api1.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.services.fastapi-api1.loadbalancer.server.port=8000'
    container_name: fastapi-api1
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    command: bash -c "sleep 10 && uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --timeout-keep-alive 240"
    restart: "on-failure:5"


  fastapi-api2:
    build:
      context: ./API2/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./files:/files"
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.fastapi-api2.rule=Host(`api2.mydomain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.fastapi-api2.entrypoints=websecure'
      - "traefik.http.routers.fastapi-api2.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - 'traefik.http.routers.fastapi-api2.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.services.fastapi-api2.loadbalancer.server.port=8001'
    container_name: fastapi-api2 
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    command: bash -c "sleep 10 && uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001"
    restart: "on-failure:5"
```

I want to remove the mariadb container and switch it to make the api's connect to the mariadb database in the local host instead.

I believe the fast api containers were setup with that command because there was a risk the database container would not be up in time for them to be able to successfully connect to it, so they were purposefully delayed. I'm not sure how, but I believe I could also clean that if they are now going to be connecting to the database.

Both api's have their connection setup in the code with blocks like

```
connection_url_api = URL.create(
    "mariadb+mariadbconnector",
    username=DB_Username_API,
    password=DB_Password_API,
    host=DB_Container_Name,
    port=3306,
    database=DB_Name_For_Api_Tables,
    query=dict(charset="utf8mb4")
)
```

I'm not sure how the environment variable `DB_Container_Name` needs to be changed, can it just be changed to `hoster.docker.internal`? It's currently just pointing to the mariadb container: `DB_Container_Name="mariadb"`.

Comment: try the answers on these question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: Does the accepted answer imply including `extra_hosts: - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"` to the docker compose file and then just using `host.docker.internal` in the connection strings (in my case, the thing that will replace DB_Container_Name)?

Comment: Running a database in a container (which will already be its own `localhost`) is fine and routine; do you need the steps in [How to deal with persistent storage (e.g. databases) in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496940/how-to-deal-with-persistent-storage-e-g-databases-in-docker) so the database data doesn't get lost?

Comment: Is it routine in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem of data storage use a volume:

At the end of your compose file:

```
volumes:
  mariadbdata: {}
```

For the `mariadb` service:

```
    volumes:
      - mariadbdata:/var/lib/mysql
```

To solve the point of MariaDB starting not completely before dependent services add to the `mariadb` service a [healthcheck](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-healthcheck-sh/):

```
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "healthcheck.sh", "--connect", "--innodb_initialized"]
    interval: 10s
    timeout: 5s
    retries: 3
```

For the services depending on `mariadb`

```
  depends_on:
    mariadb:
      condition: service_healthy
```