# Docker compose with C# and MySql

Tags: docker-compose, microservices, docker-network

I have a problem when trying to connect to dockerized mysql database from my dockerized microservice (on the same user defined bridge network).

This is my c# image:

```html
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as build
COPY ./User /microservices/User
COPY ./Associated /microservices/Associated
WORKDIR /microservices/User/User.API
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build -o /app
RUN dotnet publish -o /publish -c Debug
 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 as base
COPY --from=build  /publish /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5114
EXPOSE 5114
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "User.dll"]
# CMD ["./User"]
```

This is my compose file:

```html
services:
  user_api:
    image: df_user_api:latest
    container_name: user_api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: df_user_api
    ports: [5114:5114]
    depends_on: [mysql]
    networks: [associated]
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: roottooR1!
      MYSQL_DATABASE: webshop2023
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test123
      MYSQL_LOG_CONSOLE: "1"
      MYSQL_LOG_ERROR: "/var/log/mysql/error.log"
    ports: [3306:3306]
    networks: [associated]
    volumes:
      - "mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "mysql-log:/var/log/mysql"
      - "mysql-conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
networks:
  associated:
    name: associated
volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
  mysql-log:
    driver: local
  mysql-conf:
    driver: local
```

**error:**

```html
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
user_api  |       Connection id "0HN006R0TSPN5", Request id "0HN006R0TSPN5:00000004": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
user_api  |       MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

Confusing part is that I can connect to dockerized mysql via mysql workbench from the host machine as: localhost:3036 (because mysql is exposed towards 0.0.0.0 by default)

Same is true for locally running c# microservice, I can connect to dockerized mysql also via localhost:3036.

These are my connection strings:

From localhost:

`"server=localhost;port=3306;user=test;password=test123;database=webshop2023"`

From within docker network:

`"server=mysql;port=3306;user=test;password=test123;database=webshop2023"`

I would be delighted if someone tells me what I am doing wrong.
Sorry if the question is duplicate but I have read many articles aleready and I can't seem to figure out why it is not working.

Comment: I suspect you are just connecting before mysql has a chance to start. For MariaDB it would be like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77678844/how-to-make-docker-containerized-apis-connect-to-database-in-local-host/77682040#77682040). Making a mysql healthcheck like `mysqladmin --password=.. --protocol tcp ping` might work along with making yours a dependent on healthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that everything was right, except that MySql framework that I was using was case sensitive on linux regarding the connection string parameters.
Everyone that is developing on **windows** machine and then migrating your code to **linux** containers be exact with upper and lower case characters to not waste so much time like me.